# Is it possible to have different return types for a overloaded method?

Tags: c, overloading

In method overloading, is it possible to have different return types for a overloaded method?
for example,

```
void foo(int x) ;
int foo(int x,int y);
double foo(String str);
```

in general object oriented programming, is it possible?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584664/why-cant-two-methods-be-declared-with-the-same-signature-even-though-their-retur which is itself a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type

Answer (score 63):

In a class, there can be several methods sharing the same name but differ in

1. Parameter types
2. Number of parameters
3. Order of the parameters declared in the method

By depending on the parameters provided for the method, in the run time, compiler determines which version of the method to execute.

An overloaded method may or may not have different  return types. But return type alone is not sufficient for the compiler to determine which method is to be  executed at run time.

Comment: "in the run time, compiler determines" AFAIK in the runtime,while the program is running the compiler cannot determine anything. and Method Overloading is an example of **Compile Time Polymorphism**.

Comment: @Dunith Dhanushka why are you saying Order of Parameters? `void fun(int a, char a){
   
  }
  void fun(char a, int a){
  }` it's not working

Comment: Actually, order of parameters is unknown in C++, so -1.

Comment: One thing to add here: This is possible in Rust! blew my mind when I first saw it used there

Answer (score 31):

Method Overloading means to have two or more methods with same name in the same class with different arguments. The benefit of method overloading is that it allows you to implement methods that support the same semantic operation but differ by argument number or type.

Important Points

- Overloaded methods MUST change the argument list
- Overloaded methods CAN change the return type
- Overloaded methods CAN change the access modifier
- Overloaded methods CAN declare new or broader checked exceptions
- A method can be overloaded in the same class or in a subclass

Comment: Does "Overloaded methods CAN change the return type" and  "•Overloaded methods CAN change the access modifier" scenarios work? As per my practical experience it WONT WORK.
Eg:
public class myclass
{
    public int c = 0;
    public string Add(int a, int b)
    {
        c=a + b;
        return c.ToString();
    }
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        c = a + b;
        return c;
    }  

}

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE But the argument list is unchanged in your example, It must be changed others are optional

Answer (score 24):

It is not possible to have a method with same parameters and different `return` type.
Compiler `throws error` in the below case(Duplicate method).

**Method 1:**

```
public int calc(int a, int b, int c)
```

**Method 2:**

```
public String calc(int e, int f, int g)
```

**Error thrown:**

```
method calc(int, int, int) is already defined
```

Comment: It's also possible to overload return types of generic methods. This can be done [in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic), for example.

Answer (score 5):

No method overloading is not possible in case of different return type, because compiler can't figure that which method he need to call..

Answer (score 5):

Answer is NO.

```
Integer doSomething(){return null;}
String doSomething(){return null;}

main(){
    doSomething()
}
```

In this case compiler will never know which method to be invoked.

Note - Method Overloading is checked during compile time

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't do something like this:

```
int foo (int i, int has_default=0);
double foo (long l);
/* Skipping to the function call.  */
foo (1);
```

you should be okay.  The above code will cause problems because it could be trying to call either function.  It can get really bad if you're using C++, and you return pointers instead of primitives or references...

Answer (score 4):

In short, overloading the return type needs a powerful typing system which can derive the function to be used from the calling result.

Haskell and ML family can accomplish this job.

It's not right to define overloading to be restricted in changing the args since changing the return type leaves enough information for the compiler to derive which function to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this awesome answer, [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

In short, most statically typed languages don't, but some dynamically typed languages can.

Edit: The "In short" answer applies to overloading **strictly** by return type. As others have pointed out, if the parameter lists differ, and can be resolved by the compiler, then each method may return a different type. It **is** possible to overload methods only by return type in ADA, since the return value cannot be ignored, and the compiler can resolve the method call using this information.

Answer (score 3):

yes the example given by you is Possible we can do method ovrloading in this way in c#

```
void foo(int x)
    {
    }
    int foo(int x, int y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    double foo(String str)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: have u tried this? how will you call these functions can you explain with example for above?

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid for overloading. You can only overload by changing the parameter list. Changing the return type alone is not valid for method overloading as the return type is not part of the method signature (just the method name and parameter list are in the method signature).

Comment: the signature of a method should be like `(args, ...) -> ret_type`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Varadic template feature of C++
Hear is the Example:

```
template<typename T>
T adder(T v) {
  return v;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T adder(T first, Args... args) {
  return first + adder(args...);
}
```

And here are a couple of ways we could call it:

```
long sum = adder(1, 2, 3, 8, 7);

std::string s1 = "x", s2 = "aa", s3 = "bb", s4 = "yy";
std::string ssum = adder(s1, s2, s3, s4);
```

For the more refrence https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

For most programming languages that support method overloading (Java, C#, C++, ...), if the parameter types are different, then the return types can also be different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible *if* the parameters are also different in the overloaded method.

But if you have two methods with the same parameters and with a different return  type, it'll produce a compiler error. I repeat: Different parameters are mandatory for overloaded methods irregardless of their return type.