# Casting the Result of TableOperation.Retrieve

Tags: c#, azure

I recently got into C# / Azure and have a small problem that I'd like to work out. The application works as intended but I'd like to refactor a bunch of classes because I'm sure that there is a simpler solution.

I currently have a bunch of functions to retrieve Entities from the Azure that only vary in the Type that gets retrieved, but optimally I'd only want one class like so:

```
public static Object Do(string RowKey, string partitionKey, string tableName)
{
    var theTable = Connect.Initialize(tableName);
    var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve(
                                      Base64.EncodeTo64(partitionKey),
                                      Base64.EncodeTo64(RowKey));

    var retrievedResult = theTable.Execute(retrieveOperation);

    if (retrievedResult.Result != null) {
        return retrievedResult.Result;
    }
     throw new ArgumentException(
                 String.Format("{0} not found in the Table", RowKey));
}
```

This, in itself, works and retrieves the required entities. However, I cannot cast the returned Object without an Error.

The Object Type that I want to cast it to implements the TableEntity-Type and matches the Result out of the table.

I know that I can cast it in the sense of

```
TableOperation.Retrieve<Type>(...)
```

but I'd really like to use a single function for this purpose which requires me to cast it on calling the function.

I suspect that the problem is related to the fact that the Result is of the Type DynamicTableEntity but I am pretty lost as to why.

Is there any way to solve this problem elegantly / is there a way to establish a parameter that holds the Type that I want as a result? (I tried it with "Type ..." but that doesn't work).

Comment: Did you try using a Generic type?  As in: 
public static T Do(...) {
... 
   TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(...)
}

Comment: This API is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
return (Entity)retrievedResult.Result;

class Entity : TableEntity
{
    public string PartKey => PartitionKey;
    public string RowKey => RowKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Specify TEntity as TableEntity explicitly then cast it to generalized one

```
public async Task<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(string tableName, string partitionKey, string rowkey) where TEntity : TableEntity, new()
    {
        var table = this._tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve<TEntity>(partitionKey, rowkey));
        return (TEntity)result.Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason my cast was failing was because the `Retrieve` operation did not get all the columns needed by my type; by default it only got the PartitionKey, RowKey (and maybe ETag etc.)

To make my cast succeed, I specified the extra columns in the Retrieve call:

```
// Define the additional columns we want, and pass them into Retrieve
var columns = new List<string>(){ "Name", "Status" };
var retrieve = TableOperation.Retrieve<MyEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey, columns);
var returnedObject = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(retrieve).Result

// The cast succeeds
var myThing = (MyEntity)returnedObject;
```

For a more flexible approach, each of your TableEntity subtypes could have a static list of the columns they need `public static List<string> Columns = new List<string>() { "Name", "Status" };`

Then, to make your `Do()` generic, I think it would look something like this (not tested, you may need to do some more casting and look up some Generic magic...):

```
public static T Do<T>(string RowKey, string partitionKey, string tableName)
{
    var theTable = Connect.Initialize(tableName);
    var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(
                                      Base64.EncodeTo64(partitionKey),
                                      Base64.EncodeTo64(RowKey),
                                      T.Columns);

    var retrievedResult = theTable.Execute(retrieveOperation);

    if (retrievedResult.Result != null) {
        return retrievedResult.Result;
    }
     throw new ArgumentException(
                 String.Format("{0} not found in the Table", RowKey));
}
```

For better integrity, each of your TableEntity classes should also conform to a new Interface, like `ITableWithColumns` stipulating that the TableEntity can provide a `List<string> Columns` as described above.

There's a little bit more detail on my blog post, [Failure to cast an object from Azure TableOperation.Retrieve](http://www.stegriff.co.uk/upblog/failure-to-cast-an-object-from-azure-tableoperation-retrieve).

Answer (score -5):

You can use functions with Generic Types in c#

Refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

You can also refer the stackoverflow example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic)