# Returning generic types in c#

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class Manager<T> where T: IBallGame
{
T GetManager()
{
//if T is ISoccer return new Soccer()
//if T is IFootball return new Football()

//This wont work. Why?
if (typeof(T) == typeof(ISoccer))
                return new Soccer();
}
}

Interface ISoccer: IBallgame
{
}
class Soccer: ISoccer
{
}
Interface IFootball: IBallgame
{
}
class Football:IFootball
{
}
```

I have already checked out this question [How do I make the return type of a method generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic). Is there something more elegant than Convert.ChangeType()?

Why is it not possible to return an instance of Soccer or Football when there is a constraint on the type?

Comment: I think because Soccer and Football would need to satisfy both interfaces in order to conform to the Manager class declaration and not just one or the other.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: Why so? I am essentially merging two Manger classes into one. Without this there will be two classes SoccerManager and FootballManger, each with a method GetInstance. If checking the type of T is considered poor coding then the purpose of generic classes is rather limited dont you think?

Comment: Do you consider `List<T>` to be limited? Does it need to check the type of `T` to do its job? The point of generic classes is that the implementation of the class' methods hold regardless of the type of `T` as long as the `T` conforms to the constraints placed on the generic class. In your case, the implementation of `GetManager` is dependent on the type of `T`. You can only violate DRY if you actually RY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Manager<T> where T : class, IBallgame
{
    T GetManager()
    {
        //if T is ISoccer return new Soccer()
        //if T is IFootball return new Football()


        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ISoccer))
            return new Soccer() as T;

        //code
    }
}

public interface IBallgame
{

}
public interface ISoccer : IBallgame
{
}
public class Soccer : ISoccer
{
}
public interface IFootball : IBallgame
{
}
class Football : IFootball
{
}
```

You just need a **class** constraint and **as T**

Comment: This wont work, that's the whole problem. You will get a compile time error saying 'Cannot convert Soccer to T'

Comment: I copied it from compiled VS though. Edit just added bold statement about changes from your code.

Comment: If generics are not intended to be used like this then what is the purpose of generic return types? I cant think of a scenario where a method can return a generic type without some kind of input checking.

Comment: Have a look at generic collections from C# 2.0 release

Comment: Anything in specific: I know a bunch of them take generic types as INPUT but do any of them have methods that return generic types?

Comment: Well pretty much all of them return generic types, cause collections store generic types. Indexer on list returns T, etc.

Comment: Indexer makes sense. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: You can look into moq, autofac and fluentnhibernate libraries to get some ideas of generic use outside of collection scope.

Answer (score 5):

If you expect different implementations based on the exact type of the generic, you're not actually dealing with a generic any more.

You should define two classes, e.g. `FootBallManager : Manager<IFootball>` and `SoccerManager : Manager<ISoccer>`

Based on your update, what you actually want is an additonal constraint on your generic of `new()` and to implement your class as

```
public class Manager<T> where T: IBallGame, new()
{
    T GetManager()
    {
         return new T();         
    }
}
```

Comment: Original code from post just wont compile here new Manager<ISoccer>(); cause ISoccer doesn't fit into new() constraint

Comment: You're correct, and if that's what's wanted my original comment still holds.