# C# - Generic Method to return type according parameter

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I have this generic method:

```
    public static T FindObject<T> (this GameObject gameObject, string objectName, Type type)
    {

       var ret = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren(type).Where(w => w.name == objectName).First();

       return (T)Convert.ChangeType(ret, type);

    }
```

[image]

And I call it this way:

```
var myVar = UI_POINTS.FindObject("Score", typeof(Text));
```

[image]

But i give the following error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'ExtensionMethods.FindObject(GameObject, string, Type)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

For what reason he does not understand the method call?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to know what `T` is supposed to be?

Comment: @MatiCicero ask it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9808070/2145555

Comment: @IgoR read your own link: "But the caller will have to specify the type they expect."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what `T` is because you haven't told it, and it can't infer it from the method's parameters.  You've passed it a `Type` object as an argument, but how should the compiler know that this refers to `T`?

In fact, I'm assuming this too – and I can't be sure from your code if this is the intention.  If it is, try this instead:

```
public static T FindObject<T> (this GameObject gameObject, string objectName)
{
   var type = typeof(T);
   var ret = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren(type).Where(w => w.name == objectName).First().gameObject;

   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(ret, type);

}
```

Followed by:

```
var myVar = UI_POINTS.FindObject<Text>("Score");
```

Comment: Too quick. I had just crafted an almost identical response.

Comment: @IgoR you could also change `Type type` to `T type`. without change to your original method. then you dont have to specify types explictly

Comment: @IgoR sorry. it seems its not possible. it will be considered as `System.Type`. so this is the best way.

Comment: Yes, i tried this... but dont works! And it also does not recognize the properties of the variable, eg: myVar.text = "blabla"; he says he does not know the property '.text'.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary all right! Thanks for the comment! Cheers :)