# How to return T type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have generic method:

```
private ILogger _logger; //get logger something else.
public T GetService<T>(ServiceType type)
{
 //how to return _logger?
}
```

How can i return T?
For example, i have ILogger:

```
var logger=GetService<ILogger>(log);
```

How to implement GetService method?
Thank you!

P.S. yes, i try to get one and more types from GetService method. 
For example: Logger, some other infrastructure classes.
I know, that ServiceLocator is not right choise (is it uses in many places),but in my way (GetService will be use in one place: to get infrastructure  for my plugins) i hope it is normal.

Comment: HI @Admiral , maybe you can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic)

Comment: I would definitely not use reflection here. It is totally unnecessary @HimBromBeere

Comment: What have `ILogger` and `T` in common?

Comment: Why not make your method return `ILogger` instead of `T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to create some sort of factory method based on type. Perhaps this might help:

```
public class Factory
{
    private ILogger _logger; //get logger something else.

    public Factory()
    {
        _factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Type, object>>()
        {
            { typeof(ILogger), t => _logger },
        };
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Func<Type, object>> _factories;

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        return (T)_factories[t].Invoke(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
private ILogger _logger; //get logger something else.
public T GetService<T>(ServiceType type)
{
// codes here...
return (T)(object) _logger;
}
```

Comment: Why cast it to object? Isn't it just better to prevent cast issues as much as possible instead of circumventing them?

Answer (score 1):

I would start to make sure `T` implements `ILogger`. Then you have to cast the instance to `T`:

```
public T GetService<T>(ServiceType type) where T : ILogger
{
    return (T)_logger;
}
```

Note that this can cause invalid casts. To prevent exceptions on this and instead return null, you can use `as`:

```
public T GetService<T>(ServiceType type) where T : ILogger
{
    return _logger as T;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You have to declare `T` as `new()`, so it has to have a parameterless constructor. Then you can simply create an instance and return it:

```
    public T GetService<T>(ServiceType type) where T : new()
    {
        T t = new T();
        return t;
    }
```

Now, instead of `new T()` you could use others, may be your `ServiceType`..

Comment: You don't return `_logger`, as OP asked. You return a new instance of `T`.

Comment: It's about returning a T, that can be of type ILogger or something different.

Comment: No, as comment within code states: `//how to return _logger?`

Comment: I don't want to bother, but the main question is about a generic method returning a T. Then, as stated above, T can be of type ILogger. Otherwise, why have a generic method?

Comment: No, you don't HAVE to