# Using single method to return possible different instance types

Tags: c#, instance

So I have got these 2 instance types "FirstType" and "SecondType" which inherit from the mother class "ContaBancaria". They both return text from different textboxes. Basically, they do the same thing, but I need 2 instances for 2 different list types (I probably don't think the list has anything to do with my question, so I'll proceed not to go in detail)

Here are the instances:

```
    private FirstType AddTypeFirst()
    {
        return new FirstType(textBoxNumber.Text,
            textBoxBalance.Text,
            textBoxName.Text,
            textBoxAddress.Text,
            textBoxBirth.Text);
    }

    private SecondType AddTypeSecond()
    {
       return new SecondType(textBoxNumber.Text,
            textBoxBalance.Text,
            textBoxName.Text,
            textBoxAddress.Text,
            textBoxBirth.Text);
    }
```

Is there a way to return these 2 instances with the same method type?

EDIT:
What I meant was to return these 2 different types of instances with 1 single method, for example:

```
private [type?] AddInstance()
{
   return new [type*] textBoxNumber.Text,  //* the type could be FirstType or SecondType
            textBoxBalance.Text,
            textBoxName.Text,
            textBoxAddress.Text,
            textBoxBirth.Text);
}
```

EDIT 2:

ContaBancaria looks like this:

```
abstract class ContaBancaria
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string balance { get; set; }

    public Client data { get; set; }
}
```

And, since there's Client...

```
class Client
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string birth;
}
```

Hope you get me.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking, maybe try editing your question?

Comment: I have no Idea what you are trying to do.. if I were to guess.. you would want to use Generic Class

Comment: I have edited the question, hope you get it now...

Comment: What does the class `ContaBancaria` look like?

Comment: How would the method decide which type should be returned? You have no decision making in your example.

Comment: @NetMage When adding instance in the list, for ex: `listaCO.Add(AdicionarInstancia())`

Comment: There is no protected constructor in the abstract class?

Comment: @maccettura "We're" still learning about abstract class and stuff, we've really haven't gotten any deep into this.

Comment: What would the type of `listaCO` look like? `List<ContaOrdem>`? Again, how do you expect the function to know what type to return?

Comment: Its hard because none of your code is in English.  Are the constructors for the sub classes the same?  Meaning do they have the same parameters?

Comment: @NetMage yes, sorry for not being precise.

Comment: @maccettura I have changed it to English and removed some stuff.

Comment: Now your example is half English. Why does `AddTypeSecond` not return `SecondType`? I would have left it as is...

Comment: @NetMage Sorry for the mistake. I only wanted to provide you with easier to read variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generic method and derrived classes I think.
For example, you have two classes and you  want to receive one of them. Those classes are named "FirstSon" and "SecondSon" and both of them are derrived from class "Father".

```
class Father
{
    string myName;
    public string MyName
    {
        get { return myName; }
        set { myName = value; }
    }
    public Father()
    {
        myName = "John";
    }
}

class FirstSon : Father
{
    string mySecondName;
    public string MySecondName
    {
        get { return mySecondName; }
        set { mySecondName = value; }
    }

    public FirstSon()
    {
        mySecondName = "Bill";
    }
}

class SecondSon : Father
{
    int age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
    string mySecondName;
    public string MySecondName
    {
        get { return mySecondName; }
        set { mySecondName = value; }
    }
    public SecondSon()
    {
        mySecondName = "Drake";
        age = 21;
    }
}
```

And you have method GetObject(). This method is generic. It receives type of class, then checks what type it has received and returnes the new object with the same type.

```
    public static T GetObject<T>() where T: Father
    {
        var firstSon = new FirstSon();
        var secondSon = new SecondSon();
        if (firstSon.GetType() == typeof(T))
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(firstSon, typeof(T));
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(secondSon, typeof(T));
    }
```

It uses method Convert.ChangeType(object value, Type conversonType) and allows you to convert your object to your type.

But I am not convinced that this is a good idea according to [How do I make the return type of a method generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want to return the proper type based on the list being added to, you will need to write your own generic Add function, and use Reflection to figure out the type:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static void AddInstancia<T>(this List<T> aList) where T : class {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(FirstType))
            aList.Add(AddTypeFirst() as T);
        else
            aList.Add(AddTypeSecond() as T);
    }
}
```

I see no good reason to do this - after all, you know the type of the list, just call the correct function for that list...

Instead of using Reflection, you could also use `dynamic` if you add some functions to each sub-type:

```
public class FirstType : Parent {
    public FirstType MakeChild() {
        return new FirstType();
    }
}

public class SecondType : Parent {
    public SecondType MakeChild() {
        return new SecondType();
    }
}

public static class Static<T> where T : new() {
    public static dynamic Value = new T();
}

public static class Ext {
    public static void AddInstance<T>(this List<T> aList) where T : new() {
        aList.Add(Static<T>.Value.MakeChild());
    }
}
```

Which you can call like

```
var list1 = new List<FirstType>();

list1.AddInstance();
```

Comment: Downvotes, no explanations... perhaps downvotes should be like close votes and require a comment.