# Custom return type based on input data

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a method which takes an interface type and evaluates what the type is and from that I need to return a type related to it. But I'm not sure how to make the type returns flexible for it. I tried something like this:

```
public static T GridPosition <T>(IReSizeableGrid gridData) {
  if (gridData is Hex) {
    var hexGrid = (HexGrid) gridData;
    return HexLibrary.WorldToHex(WorldPoint(Input.mousePosition, GroundPlane), hexGrid);
  }
  if (gridData is QuadGrid) {
    var quadGrid = (QuadGrid) gridData;
    return Grid.Get(WorldPoint(Input.mousePosition, GroundPlane), quadGrid);
  }
  throw new Exception("Wrong type passed to GridPosition: " + gridData.GetType());
}
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Hex to T`

Am I on the right lines here using `T`? Trying to understand how to use it properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic

Comment: Hmm the answer in that link seems to suggest its not a good idea to do it that way. Does that mean my design might be wrong/bad ?

Comment: That question is different from yours, so the recommendations can be different. It seems that `Hex` and `QuadGrid` implement `IReSizeableGrid`, right? If yes, then why do you use generics for the returned type? You could simply return `IReSizeableGrid`.

Comment: @RacilHilan was trying to avoid the user utilising my library from having to cast it themselves. I'd like it to just work without them worrying about it.

Comment: I see. Then it is not necessarily bad to use a generic function. It's hard to tell without seeing how it is used and what those sub-functions do. In general, it is recommended that each function does one job only. See my answer for how to do it if you want to continue with a generic function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes generics aren't the right answer. You'd only use generics if you want to do the ***same thing*** to two or more related types. In this case, you are doing completely different things, so you actually need to use [method overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) instead.

```
public static Point GridPosition(HexGrid gridData)
{
    return HexLibrary.WorldToHex( WorldPoint( Input.mousePosition, GroundPlane), gridData);
}

public static Point GridPosition(QuadGrid gridData)
{
    return Grid.Get(WorldPoint(Input.mousePosition, GroundPlane), gridData);
}
```

You can call either of these with the same code:

```
var result = GridPosition(new HexGrid());
var result = GridPosition(new QuadGrid());
```

...and the compiler will pick the right version for you.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you :) I shall take a read into overloading. Seems my google skills lead me down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Hex` and `QuadGrid` implement `IReSizeableGrid`, you can make the type of the `gridData` parameter also `T`, and then restrict `T` to `IReSizeableGrid`:

```
public static T GridPosition<T>(T gridData) where T : IReSizeableGrid {
    if (gridData is Hex) {
        var hexGrid = (HexGrid) gridData;
        return (T)HexLibrary.WorldToHex(WorldPoint(Input.mousePosition, GroundPlane), hexGrid);
    }
    if (gridData is QuadGrid) {
        var quadGrid = (QuadGrid)gridData;
        return (T)Grid.Get(WorldPoint(Input.mousePosition, GroundPlane), quadGrid);
    }
    throw new Exception("Wrong type passed to GridPosition: "+gridData.GetType());
}
```

You don't need to specify the type `<T>` when calling the function. It will be taken from the type of the `gridData` parameter.