# Returning custom generic methods in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to return a custom generic type from a method that accepts the generic type.
I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic) post, but it does not explain how a custom return type will be handled as I need to convert the my custom type to the generic type.

What is the recommended method to convert a custom type to a generic type?

For example:
I would like to call:

```
var users = GetUsers<UsersDto>();
```

where

```
internal IQueryable<T> GetUsers<T>()
{
    var result = from u in db.Users
                 select new UsersDto()
                 {
                    UserID = u.ID,
                    UserName = u.Name
                 };
     return result;  //This is the problem as it can't convert UsersDto to T
}
```

**EDIT:**

GetUsers are probably too specific and might be confusing on why the use of generics is appropriate.
GetUsers should rather be called something like GetGridResults which will reside in a base class.  Each child class will populate the grid with different results.

Comment: What should be the relation between `T` and  `UserDto`... Why should it be legal?

Comment: The <T> in GetUsers are coming from an abstract in the base class. Maybe GetUsers as a method name is not the best. Something like GetGridData makes it more generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to return an `IQueryable<UsersDto>` from a method that promises to return `IQueryable<T>`, there must be a relation between `T` and `UsersDto`.

You could do this by introducing an interface, applying that to the DTO and constraining the generic parameter to that interface:

```
public interface IUserDto
{
    int UserID { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto : IUserDto { ... }

public IQueryable<TUserDto> GetUsers<TUserDto>()
    where TUserDto : class, IUserDto, new()
{
    // ...
        new TUserDto
        {
            UserID = u.ID,
            UserName = u.Name
        }
    // ...
}
```

The interface is optional, you could also directly constrain to `UserDto`.

Comment: Well, almost all the answers point to the same solution. I will accept this one as it was first. I am not going to go the interface route as it is optional and just adds a level of complexity.  Thanks to all!!!!

Comment: Thanks, but do note that [bommelding has a point as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50603441/).

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to return a type that has the properties `UserId` and `UserName`, there has to be either a base class or an interface that the type you want to pass as `T` implements. Then, the generic method must be able to infer that the generic type parameter does in fact have those properties. Furthermore, you need the `new()` constraint to be able to easily create a new object that satisfied the type constraint.

Try

```
interface IUser
{
     int UserId { get; set; }
     string UserName { get; set; }
}

internal IQueryable<T> GetUsers<T>()
    where T : IUser, new()
{
    var result = from u in db.Users
         select new T()
         {
            UserID = u.ID,
            UserName = u.Name
         };
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- To be able to do the `new T()` and then set the `UsersDto` fields you need to set some constraints on the generic parameter (`where T : UsersDto, new()`). Clearly `T` must then be `UsersDto` or a super-class of `UsersDto`.
- To have a `IQueryable<T>`, if `db.Users` is already a `IQueryable<User>` then you already have a `IQueryable<T>`, otherwise use `.AsQueryable()`, but note that it will be a "fake" `IQueryable<>` in this case (a `IQueryable<>` executed on the local machine)

```
internal IQueryable<T> GetUsers<T>() where T : UsersDto, new()
{
    var result = from u in db.Users
                 select new T()
                 {
                     UserID = u.ID,
                     UserName = u.Name
                 };
    return result;
    // return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should not come up. You can twist yourself into an answer but the error happened earlier.

I think that GetUsers is part of a Service class. We can then have

```
public interface IUserService<T> { IEnumerable<T> GetUsers(); }

public MyUserService : IUserService<UserDTO>
{
   public IEnumerable<UserDTO> GetUsers() { /* no problems here */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
internal IQueryable<T> GetUsers<T>() where T : UsersDto, new()
{
    var result = from u in db.Users
                 select new T()
                 {
                    UserID = u.ID,
                    UserName = u.Name
                 };
     return result;  //It is IQueryable<UsersDto> now
}
```

But I don't think this is what you want it to be. Generic methods can't know what they sholud do with that type T, and how they should create objects of it;
You also can pass lambda to method which will be executed to generate object of type T, but it doesn't looks as clean code and a way to go.

May be you can share your idea that leaded you to this problem?

Comment: The problem originated is that my base class needs to print results of different formats. If you rename GetUsers to PrintResults the whole thing makes a little more sense. Each child class will pass a seperate T to be printed.