# Typed parameter method to initialize a type ... Why is this invalid?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Example of what I'm trying to do

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

    }

    private static T Initialize<T>() where T : MyInterface
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyImplementation))
        {
            return new MyImplementation();  
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported type");
    }
}

public interface MyInterface
{

}

public class MyImplementation : MyInterface
{

}
```

To me this seems like it should work (the compiler should know that `NewImplementation` is a `T` since `T` is a `MyInterface`).

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyImplementation' to 'T'

Why is this wrong and what is the correct way?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @JoeSewell Just added it

Comment: You may want to take a look at this post. It has some options that sound like they may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic

Comment: You may be able to cast it to an object, then to T. An alternative may be Convert.ChangeType() - although I've never used it to know how it functions internally.

Comment: The compiler isn't doing static code analysis on this level, it doesn't understand that your if-statement guarantees that T will be that type. Also, define "correct". You're doing checks for specific types in a generic method, in my *opinion*, there is no correct way to do that because you're using the concepts wrong. However, to *get the code to compile* you can just cast to `T`: `(T)new MyImplementation();`. If that doesn't work, do `(T)(object)new MyImplementation();`. If you think this is wonky, you're right, because you're doing wonky things.

Answer (score 4):

The return type `T` might not be a `MyImplementation`, for example, if we had another type `MyOtherImplementation`:

```
public class MyOtherImplementation : MyInterface { }
```

Then we call the `Initialize<T>` method, this would return a `MyOtherImplementation`:

```
MyOtherImplementation myInterface = Initialize<MyOtherImplementation>();
```

You'll need to change the return type to the below to make this work as you expect:

```
    private static MyInterface Initialize<T>() where T : MyInterface
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyImplementation))
        {
            return new MyImplementation();
        }
        throw new Exception("Unsupported type");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Kevin Smith's answer you can add `new` into `where` i.e. ensure that every `T` class has a default constructor

```
// "where ..., new" - each T must have a default constructor
private static T Initialize<T>() where T : MyInterface, new {
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyImplementation)) {
    return new T(); // <- now we can create T which is in fact MyImplementation
  }
  throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported type");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kevin's answer must be solving your concern.

But if due to any reason you don't want to change signature of your method, you can easily cast your object into `T` and then return it.

It will be the same at calling side and will be compatible at method body.

```
private static T Initialize<T>() where T : MyInterface
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyImplementation))
    {
        MyInterface obj = new MyImplementation(/*parameters*/);
        return (T)obj;
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported type");
}
```

this will handle the scene when you have to pass parameters too while instantiating an object which I am not sure can be possible in the approach of Dmitry !