# Instantiate object depending on type

Tags: c#

I have a function that reads a CSV file and returns a list of objects whose parameters depends on the content of the CSV. Right now it works if I hardcode one object. I would like to return different object types.

```cs
    public static List<CSVObject> ImportCsvIntoObject(string csvFile, string delimiter)
    {
        List<CSVObject> list = new List<CSVObject>();

        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csvFile))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new String[] { delimiter });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            //Parse the file and creates a list of CSVObject
            //example with a csv file with 3 columns
            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                string parameter1 = fieldData[0];
                string parameter2 = fieldData[1];
                string parameter3 = fieldData[2];

                CSVObject example = new CSVObject(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
                list.Add(example);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The following solution works but I'm not sure if there are not better ways to do this.

```cs
    public static List<Object> ImportCsvIntoList(string csvFile, string delimiter, Type type)
    {
        List<Object> list = new List<Object>();

        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csvFile))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new String[] { delimiter });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {

                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                string parameter1 = fieldData[0];
                string parameter2 = fieldData[1];
                string parameter3 = fieldData[2];

                var example = Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
                list.Add(example);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Furthermore, right now it only works with a hardcoded amount of parameters. Unfortunately, my objects all have a different amount of parameters. How can I call Activator.CreateInstance with different amount of parameters ?

It is my first question so sorry if it isn't written properly, suggestion to improve are more than welcome.

Comment: If it works, then you should post this at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: rather than list of object...it should be list of t...use generics - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic

Comment: *How can I call Activator.CreateInstance with different amount of parameters ?* Use the overload that accepts a type and a arbitrary number of objects?

Comment: Read a portion of the file to learn what type it is, then your code can know which of several types to create without resorting to `List<Object>`

Comment: LarsTech thanks for the link I'll have a look I didn't know about it.

Ctznkane525 and mm8 thank you I'll look into it.

Make StackOverflow Good Again I actually receive the type as parameter so I don't even need to read the file. But Activator.CreateInstance seems to create an object of type object so when I do myList.Add I get "cannot convert from object to ..."

Comment: Use the @ sign in front of a user name in comments to reply directly to that person.

Comment: @LarsTech I wanted to do that but it only lets me do it for one person per comment.

Comment: That's been a limitation from day one.  Not sure why, but oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might work for you using generics and delegates

```
public static List<T> ImportCsvIntoObject<T>(string csvFile, string delimiter, Func<List<string>, T> createObject)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csvFile))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new String[] { delimiter });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            //Parse the file and creates a list of CSVObject
            //example with a csv file with 3 columns
            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

                CSVObject example = createObject(fieldData.ToList())
                list.Add(example);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And you would call the following using:

```
List<CSVObject> objectList = ImportCsvIntoObject("csvData", ",", (list) => { new CSVObject(list[0], list[1], list[2]); });
```

Comment: That answer looks interesting, I'll try it, thank you.
The only problem is that it still limits me to objects with 3 parameters. Would it be possible to do Func<ArrayList, T> instead so that I can put as many parameter as needed in the arraylist ?

Comment: @SachaDieryck I've edited the above, It does seem a little error prone now though since you have to trust the csv will provide you with the correct output. Have you looked into using CSVHelper at all? It would be better if you could map your csv data directly to an object.

Comment: I didn't know about CSVHelper, it looks like it does the job quite well actually, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The `Activator.CreateInstance()` function can take [an array of parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___), so that you might not know how many you need before runtime, but as you read your CSV, you create arrays corresponding to the number of parameters needed for this particular object (fortunately, your field data object seems to already do this).

So it could be like this :

```
string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

var example = Activator.CreateInstance(type, fieldData);
list.Add(example);
```

This is because the `Activator.CreateInstance` function uses the [params keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)