# Using a Type value as generic type

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Type MyType = typeof(SomeClass);
SomeMethod<MyType>();
```

Where `SomeMethod` is,

```
T SomeMethod<T>() where T : TypeOfSomeClass {
   ...

   return NewInstanceOfT;
}
```

This fails, of course. I want to store the *type* of a class and later use that type (**the value** of `MyType`) as the generic type for a method.

This is an use case as an example:

```
class WindowService {
    public static T CreateWindow<T>() where T : Window {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}

... (in some other class) ...

Type TypeOfWindow = typeof(MyConcreteWindow);

void CreateAWindow() {
    Window Obj = WindowService.CreateWindow<TypeOfWindow>();
}
```

`CreateWindow<T>` should create an instance of whatever class is stored in `TypeOfWindow`, as long as it extends `Window`.

Comment: Not really. I want to use the value of `MyType` (which has type `Type`) as the generic type. I don't have an instance like him, just the type.

Comment: Take a closer look. `typeof(ClassWithSomeMethod).GetMethod("SomeMethod").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass)).Invoke();`  The key concept here is to take a generic method definition and make a close-constructed method definition, which you can then invoke.

Comment: `typeof(WindowService).GetMethod("CreateWindow").MakeGenericMethod(TypeOfWindow).Invoke(...);`

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If 'm not mistaken about what you want to accomplish, it's done like this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T t) where T : SomeClassOrInterface{ // Code }
```

According to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) (It's one of the examples at the bottom of the page)

EDIT: If you want to return an object of type T, it's something like this

```
public T Whatever<T>(string values)
{  
    return /* code to convert the setting to T... */
}
```

In this case, you can check more details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808035/how-do-i-make-the-return-type-of-a-method-generic)