# c++ error - function cannot be overloaded

Tags: c++

Following is a c++ code for copying a binary tree. I am trying to overload copy function. I think it should work because return type of these two functions is different.

```
node* copy(node *onode,node *cnode)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        root=onode;
    if(onode)
    {
        cnode=new node;
        cnode->data=onode->data;
        cnode->left=copy(onode->left,cnode->left);
        cnode->right=copy(onode->right,cnode->right);
        return cnode;
    }
        return cnode;
}

void copy(node *onode,node* cnode)
{
    onode=copy(onode,cnode);
}
```

However, I get following error at compilation.

> error: ‘void tree::copy(node*, node*)’ cannot be overloaded
>        void copy(node *onode,node* cnode)
>   error: with ‘node* tree::copy(node*, node*)’
>        node* copy(node *onode,node *cnode)

Thanks.

Comment: If I call `copy(a, b)`,where `a` and `b` are `node*`, which version do you expect the compiler to call? How could it possibly know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807840/is-it-possible-to-have-different-return-types-for-a-overloaded-method

Comment: The second version of `copy` doesn't make any sense. Why change the value of `onode` but then do nothing with the new value? I think you meant `void copy(node **onode,node* cnode)
{
    *onode=copy(*onode,cnode);
}`. This will fix your error as well.

Answer (score 1):

Return types can be different only if parameters are different according to rules of overloading

Comment: Where can I read the formal rules?