# C# overloading with generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics

Why those two methods cannot have the same name? Is it because C# compiler does not take the generic type constraints into consideration for overloading? Could it be done in future releases of C#?

```
public static TValue GetValueOrNull<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
            where TValue : class
{
    TValue value;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        return value;
    return null;
}

public static TValue? GetValueOrNull<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
        where TValue : struct
{
    TValue value;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        return value;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Names are different here. Don't see any problem. What error you get?

Comment: He changed the names himself, it should be **TValue GetValueOrNull** and **TValue? GetValueOrNull**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't two methods be declared with the same signature even though their return types are different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584664/why-cant-two-methods-be-declared-with-the-same-signature-even-though-their-retu)

Comment: @Uriel_SVK: It's not a duplicate of that - the OP hoped that generic constraints would be part of the signature, and they're not.

Comment: See https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints.aspx and https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx here is also a good article

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely correct. See section 3.6 of the [C# Language Spec (version 5)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the **number of type parameters** and the type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal parameters, considered in the order left to right. **For these purposes, any type parameter of the method that occurs in the type of a formal parameter is identified not by its name, but by its ordinal position in the type argument list of the method**. *The signature of a method specifically does not include* the return type, the params modifier that may be specified for the right-most parameter, nor *the optional type parameter constraints.*

(My emphasis)

So the signature of both methods is effectively:

```
GetValueOrNull<T1,T2>(IDictionary<T1,T2>,T1)
```

And:

> Overloading of methods permits a class, struct, or interface to declare multiple methods with the same name, *provided their signatures are unique* within that class, struct, or interface.

---

> Could it be done in future releases of C#?

I doubt it, unless or until type inference becomes an easier problem to solve. Type inference can already take large amounts of time because the compiler usually has to perform a brute-force approach. It having to also consider overload resolution at the same time may be prohibitively expensive given current machines.

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be done in future releases of C#?

With the emergence of nullable reference types, this has become possible today, but the type parameters must appear in the parameter list.

```
public static bool GetValueOrNull<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key, out TValue? value) where TValue : class
{
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
}

public static bool GetValueOrNull<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key, out TValue? value) where TValue : struct
{
    if(dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out TValue v))
    {
        value = v;
        return true;
    }
    value = null;
    return false;
}
```