# Java - why no return type based method overloading?

Tags: java, programming-languages, return, overloading

I know this is not possible but can anyone provide a theory as to why Java chose not to support this?  I am asking because I just ran into a situation where I *think* it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Because you are not required to capture the return value of a method in Java, in which case the compiler can not decide which overload to use. E.g.

```
boolean doSomething() { ... }

int doSomething() { ... }

doSomething(); // which one to call???
```

Comment: Interestingly, the Java language forbids this, but the JVM does not. See my answer...

Comment: @PéterTörök but why inheritance required same return type? why not Hiding concept works there? here I posted the question but no answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957019/why-return-type-of-same-named-method-should-be-same-in-sub-class-java

Answer (score 35):

One interesting aspect about this question is the fact that the Java language forbids overloading methods only by return type. But not the JVM:

> Note that there may be more than one
>   matching method in a class because
>   while the Java language forbids a
>   class to declare multiple methods with
>   the same signature but different
>   return types, the Java virtual machine
>   does not. This increased flexibility
>   in the virtual machine can be used to
>   implement various language features.
>   For example, covariant returns can be
>   implemented with bridge methods; the
>   bridge method and the method being
>   overridden would have the same
>   signature but different return types.

From: [Class.getMethod(String, Class...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-)

Comment: Yes, the depths of the JVM. Also, with generic method parameters there are some very nice JVM tricks that apply using "synthetic" methods, which don't exist in the Java language, either...

Comment: @LukasEder: well, they *kind-of* apply to the Java language, because the compiler will occasionally produce synthetic methods (for example for return type covariance).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Yes, you could say that... well the compiler uses a JVM feature, but the user cannot use that feature explicitly...

Answer (score 14):

I've wondered why they don't support this also. Sure, if you ignore the return value, the compiler would have no way to know which you wanted. But that's the same ambiguity that arises with passing nulls. Like:

```
String doSomething(String s) { ... }
String doSomething(Integer s) { ... }
...
String out=doSomething(null);
```

In this case, the compiler just complains that the call is ambiguous, and you have to resolve it by casting the null, like:

```
String out=doSomething((String)null);
```

You could do the same thing with overloading by return type:

```
String getSomething() { ... }
Integer getSomething() { ... }
...
Integer n=getSomething();
```

would presumably call the second function.

```
getSomething();
```

would be ambiguous (and in this example, probably useless, unless it had side effects, but that's another story), so you'd have to say:

```
(String) getSomething();
```

More realistically, perhaps:

```
if ((String) getSomething()==null) ...
```

But that's the easy case. I can see a compiler-writer not wanting to support this because it could get very complicated to figure out in anything other than a simple assignment. For example, consider:

```
String getSomething() { ... };
Integer getSomething() { ... };
String getOtherthing() { ... };
...
if (getSomething().equals(getOtherthing())) ...
```

The compiler would have to figure out that both String and Integer have equals functions, so either one is valid at that point. Then it would have to notice that getOtherthing is a String, and Integer.equals(String) is unlikely, so probably what the writer wanted was String.equals(String). Do-able, but at that point I'm starting to see that in the general case, this could be a beast.

And then suppose we add:

```
Integer getOtherthing() { ... };
```

Now what does the compiler do with that IF statement? It could use the String versions of both functions, or the Integer, but not the String of one and the Integer of the other. At that point it would have to insist on a cast to tell it which, I guess. But the complexity is really getting out of hand.

And if it's hard for the compiler to figure out what you really mean, imagine what it would be like for another programmer who can't look up all the function signatures as fast as the compiler can.

Comment: If I were designing the language/framework, I would require that all overloads but one for any signature must be marked as "secondary"; such overloads would only be considered if the function's return value would explicitly be cast or coerced via assignment to a particular type, or--for secondary overloads returning `void`--if it would be totally ignored.  In cases where a return value is passed as a parameter to some other function, the secondary overloads would not be considered.  I think such rules would avoid ambiguity, while allowing some useful optimizations.

Comment: You'd still get in trouble. What if we had "primary String doX" and "secondary Integer doX", and then also "primary Integer doY" and "secondary String doY"? Then we write "if (dox().equals(doY())". Do we use the primary of doX and thus the String versions of both functions, or the primary of doY and thus the Integer versions of both functions? Ultimately you would end up having situations where you had to somehow specify which you meant -- like a syntax to say "doX%String%()" or some such -- and/or there would have to be some arbitrary and probably confusing rules for which got picked.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are free to ignore return value.

Answer (score 3):

While it is theoretically possible, it was not used in Java for the same reason it wasn't used in C++; namely, it has been found that overloads based on return-types are generally more confusing to developers, the benefit is marginal compared with the costs of implementing it, and  it would be ambiguous in the case where the return-type is not assigned to a value. For those reasons return-type based overloading is not supported.

Comment: Confusing to developers AND compilers, especially if the call isn't used in a context where a return value is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the reasons is that, in most case you can determine the return type of a function only after the execution of the function instead of before this process. Thus, it can not help you decide which overloaded function to invoke just based on different return types of functions.

Comment: This is a good reason in a dynamic language, however in Java the method signature to call (including return type) is resolved at compile time, so since the return type is understood by the compiler, it could theoretically resolve this (if not for the issue in the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

overloading function only on the basis of return type is confusing for the compiler to distinguish between the calls, because at the time of invocation you are not giving the return type, as in the case with the parameters, so you only give the parameter list and this parameter list is the only way for the compiler to distinguish between the function calls, and return value is received at the completion of the function, that is why return type does not contributes to the signature of the function

Answer (score -1):

Method overloading uses compile time polymorphism technique. 
Method overriding uses run time polymorphism technique.

**Method overloading:**

As said in previous answers, java does not support method overloading with different return type and same arguments. This is because, it has to determine which method to use at the compile time itself. To remove the ambiguity, they designed the method overloading technique like this.

If we really need method overloading with different types and same arguments, it is possible to some extent with mehtod overriding.

**Method overriding:**

Method overriding uses run-time polymorphism technique. Hence which method to execute is not decided at compile time and it is decided at run-time by JVM.

With co-variant return types, we can have different return type in the sub class's method with same arguments as base class.

Example of co-variant return type:

```
            class BaseClass {
                BaseClass dosomething(){
                    System.out.println("Print BaseClass");
                    return this;
                }

            }

            class AnotherBaseClass extends BaseClass {
                @Override
                BaseClass dosomething(){
                    System.out.println("Print AnotherBaseClass");
                    return this;
                }
            }



            class SubClass extends AnotherBaseClass {
                @Override
                SubClass dosomething(){ /*Here SubClass is co-vairantreturn type*/ 
                    System.out.println("Print SubClass");
                    return this;
                }
                public static void main(String args[]){
                  SubClass s1 = new SubClass();
                  s1.dosomething();
                }
            }
```

Output:

Print SubClass

Answer (score -2):

Because Java can cast the return type value to the target variable, so it doesn't know into what variable type are you storing the return value of the function.