# Operator- overloading (same parameters, different return type)

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

How do I overload the minus operator accepting the same number of parameters, but having different return types?

Template class:

```
template <typename T>
T minus (T x, T y) {
    return (x - y);
}

template <typename T>
double absMinus (T x, T y) {
    double sd = abs(x - y);
    return sd;
}
```

Operator overloading class:

```
Minus operator-(Minus &p, Minus &q) {
    return (p.something - q.something);
}

double operator-(Minus &p, Minus &q) {
    return (p.something() - q.something());
}
```

When I tried to compile, it gave me the following error:

```
Minus.h:25: error: new declaration ‘double operator-(Minus&, Minus&)’
Minus.h:24: error: ambiguates old declaration ‘Minus operator-(Minus&, Minus&)’
```

Comment: You can not overload functions on return-type only.

Comment: Say you have `Minus p, x;`. What do **you** expect `p-x;` to return? You don't assign the result to anything, just write `p-x;`.

Comment: Note : You should return a const or reference to const with this kind of operator. Otherwise, you'll be able to write silly statements such as `(a - b) = c;`

Comment: @JBL no, you're mistaking.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Oh ? I thought so, and that this would make for example typo in conditional statements (i.e. missing one = ) stand out with a compile-time error...

Comment: @JBL returning a reference would lead to undefined behavior, because a temporary is created from `p.something - q.something`. Would you allocate an object dynamically just so you can return by reference, even though you shouldn't? Regardless, no, `operator -` shouldn't return a const reference.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Woops, indeed, I think should be only const, not -reference to const... My bad. (I think I overlapped with the ?= family of operators...)

Comment: @JBL those are different. And yes, those should return references, but not `const` ones, to enable chaining.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Indeed, I mixed the two...

Comment: Can I know how to go about with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Overloading can be done only when the parameter list is different. For example:

```
int myFun(int);
double myFun(int);
```

Now you are calling `myFun(10)`. Compiler has no way to determine which version to call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, overload resolution chooses an overload based only on the types of function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading is just an extension of function/method overloading. For function overloading, the signature of the functions should be different. As reported in your post, the signatures of the two functions are the same.

Please note that function/method signature doesn't include the return type.

Read this for more on this topic here: [Java - why no return type based method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744511/java-why-no-return-type-based-method-overloading)