# Why return type cannot change when overloading a method in Java

Tags: java

I know that to overload a method in Java, we need to change something in the parameters, either the number of the arguments or the type of at least one of them. This way at compile time the compiler is able to statically bind the method that will be called, but I'm just curious to know why is not enough to change the return type of the method, the first response would be because ambiguity but in my opinion if we have:

```
public class Test {
    public Integer method1(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public String method1(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return "test";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = method1(2, 4);
    }
}
```

I know this code does not compile, but my question is: Wouldn't it be possible that the compiler check the return type that we are expecting to have and based on that, bind the the call to the right method?

EDIT: I want to be perfectly clear in my question I DO know that only the parameters are part of the signature of a method, I know that we can have methods returning nothing so, there we have an ambiguity so that a compilation error should be raised, but what about the cases where we have no ambiguity at all?? Like the example I proposed... Would it be doable? Does someone know a special reason to not do it?

Comment: How would it compile `Object o = method1(2, 4);`. Or simply `method1(2, 4);`?

Comment: And what if I like to call the method like `method1(1, 2);` without storing the returned value? What should the JVM call?

Comment: @Tom A rule can always be invented, for example perhaps an absence of return target causes ambiguity error. That's why Q&A like this are totally speculative.

Comment: @Radiodef A rule like this could be really annoying, if you need to store the returned value in a temp variable, just to avoid a compiler error. But I would consider this kind of overloading a code smell anyway, so I wouldn't get in touch with this rule :D.

Comment: There are quite a few answers about this. Just search for "method overload java return type".

Comment: As a side note, one can solve this problem by simply using different method names.

Answer (score 4):

Method overloading is based on altering the signature of the method.  Since the signature of the method [does not include the return type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), you have to differentiate these two methods on parameters alone.

[From the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):  the *only* things that comprise of a signature of a method and constructor declaration are its **name** and its **argument types.**

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and
>   argument types.
>
> Two method or constructor declarations M and N have the same argument
>   types if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - They have the same number of formal parameters (possibly zero)
> - They have the same number of type parameters (possibly zero)
> - Let A<sub>1</sub>, ..., A<sub>n</sub> be the type parameters of M and let B<sub>1</sub>, ..., B<sub>n</sub> be the type parameters of N.
>     After renaming each occurrence of a B<sub>i</sub> in N's type to
>     A<sub>i</sub>, the bounds of corresponding type variables are the
>     same, and the formal parameter types of M and N are the same.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>
> - m<sub>2</sub> has the same signature as m<sub>1</sub>, or
> - the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>.
>
> Two method signatures m<sub>1</sub> and m<sub>2</sub> are
>   override-equivalent iff either m<sub>1</sub> is a subsignature of
>   m<sub>2</sub> or m<sub>2</sub> is a subsignature of m<sub>1</sub>.
>
> **It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.**

That, and that *alone* is why your statement does not compile; you're passing in an `Integer` and an `Integer` to two identical* methods, and Java cannot disambiguate between them.

This means that a declaration like this is *perfectly legal*:

```
public Integer method1(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return null;
}

public void method1(Integer c) {
}
```

...because of the difference in parameter types to the two methods.

<sub>*:  "identical" as far as the compiler is concerned.</sub>

Comment: That's what OP already knows. He asks why the return type isn't enough for method overloading (or why isn't the return type part of the signature).

Comment: I've added a reference from the JLS to highlight that return type is explicitly not considered in the signature of a method.

Comment: I can get behind this answer. Answer with the facts, because that is the answer we can give.

Comment: OP already knows that the return type is not part of the signature, but he doesn't know why. This should be part of the answer (if one is able to answer that with facts why the language design made that choice).

Comment: @Tom:  The only people that could definitively answer *why* that's not part of the signature are the language designers themselves.  It's also likely a hold-over from C in which the signature of a function is its name and argument types.

Comment: I know that only the parameters are considered in the signature of a method, I was just wondering if wouldn't be possible to include the return type as we know at compilation time what we are expecting to return. But i guess this is not done because it would add complexity by adding a rule when the method returns nothing.

Comment: As I've pointed out from official documentation, the return type is not considered at all in the method signature.  That's the long and short of it, really.

Comment: Well, then you could add that info to your answer, so the (later) readers know, why you don't "answer" that part of the question.

Comment: @Tom:  I'm not sure I understand - I'm fairly certain that I do add the information about the return type not being considered as part of the signature.  Could you be a bit more clear as to what clarifications I would need to make for this answer?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, you told him, that it isn't considered as part of the signature, but not _why_. I know you can't tell him why exactly its acting like that, but you _could_ outline that by providing an example how this could fail or be error-prone. Since this is the question, it should be part of the answer.

Comment: Right.  So, what I think I'll do is make it clear that the reference is coming from the language specification.  That *should* satisfy the why portion of it; the language has explicitly prohibited it.   @Tom, I'm not entirely sure what the whole back-and-forth about why I hadn't explained it concisely enough was.  The fact remains - the language has prohibited it.

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this yourself by asking yourself which method would be called in the following scenario:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object result = method1(2, 4);
}
```

Comment: Clearly the one returning an `Object` is called or an ambiguity error is raised. How does this at all validate or invalidate the suggestion by the OP?

Comment: The op does not suggest anything, but instead asks a question, which is - in my opinion - answered by what I wrote. I didn't want to invalidate his question but instead give him pointers as to how to get the answer by himself.

Comment: muued , but the case you are suggesting, either we have ambiguity so that we get a compilation error or we could add a new method returning specifically an Object. But in the case where we have no ambiguity at all, like the one I proposed, it is not really clear why that could not be doable.

Comment: *"which is - in my opinion - answered by what I wrote"* But you did not explain how. And, as I pointed out, rules can be invented to deal with the case in your answer, just as the OP is suggesting rules be invented to allow this. The Java language has rules for handling overload ambiguity, so why do you think an ambiguity is relevant as an answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745051/3661794 goes into more detail concerning the troubles of allowing return type based method overloading