# why java compiler can't decide which method to call based on return type

Tags: java

I've read this topic:
[Java - why no return type based method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744511/java-why-no-return-type-based-method-overloading)

However I am still puzzled, because when looking into the java byte code:

> invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;

It 's very clear that the the descriptor of different methods with different return types is identifiable.

```
return type is void: ()V
return type is int: ()I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the compiled code, i.e. you're assuming the compiler *can* decide which method to compile. But the problem is it can't (for the same reason in the answer to the mentioned post). The compiler does not read bytecode, it produces it. What reads the bytecode is the JVM.

Don't confuse between defining the methods and using them. Technically you can define both

```
int foo()
void foo()
```

But then imagine someone just calls `foo()` in his/her code without possibly assigning the return value to a variable. How would the compiler know the call to which method to place in the compiled code?

Comment: if the compiler can't tell, how can it produce ()V if return type is void and do ()I if return type is an Integer?

Comment: @user2229323 You're confusing between defining the methods and using them. Technically you can define both `int foo()` and `void foo()`. But then imagine someone just calls `foo()` in his/her code. How would the compiler know the call to which method to place in the compiled code?

Comment: yes! the return type can be ignored when being called! thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in identifying the descriptor of the method uniquely, or producing an image that has multiple methods with identical signature and different return types. It is identifying the desired return type from the context that presents a problem.

When a method returns a value, a method call is an *expression*, not a statement. Therefore, the value produced by the expression is subject to conversion rules defined in the language. Because of these conversion rules Java would have problems deciding what method to call even in seemingly simple situations like this:

```
String foo();
Integer foo();
...
Integer a = foo(); // No problem here
String b = foo();  // This is fine, too
Object c = foo();  // Which overload should be called?
```

Note that the compiler would have full knowledge of the return types of both overloads. Yet in does not have enough information to make a decision on the last line in the simple example above.

Note that solving these problems is not impossible: a syntax can be introduced or additional requirements could be made to allow the compiler to resolve overloads based on the return type. For example, they could require programmers to insert a cast:

```
Object c = (Integer)foo();
```

However, doing this is impractical, because the additional syntax would not solve a problem, but shift it from one place to another, because type resolution would remain programmers' responsibility.

Comment: yes, maybe the superclass is one of considering issue, but i think the calling  without requirement of return type is the best reason. thanks so much BTW