# Java function that returns diferent types

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a getTag function and i would like to pass along side the TagName the returning type. My teacher told me that in C we can pass by reference and make multiple function with the first parameter the same and the other the type of return, and i would like to do something like that.

I'm saving in a txt file the last index as the type like:

```
Nome ; Ricardo ; String
Horas Jogo ; 1700 ; String
Frutas ; Bananas ; String
Horas ; 1700 ; Int
```

For example:

```
int n; 
n = ob.getTag("Horas", n);
```

and have something like:

```
public String getTag(String name, String info) {
    System.out.println("getTag - Nome da Tag: " + name);
    Tag aux;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        aux = Tags.get(i);
        i++;
    } while (!aux.TagName.equals(name) && i < Tags.size());
    if (aux.TagName.equals(name)) {
        if (aux.TagInfoTipo.equals("String")) {
            return aux.TagInfo;
        } else if (!aux.TagInfoTipo.equals("String")) 
            return null;//add throw exception

    }


public int getTag(String name, int info) {
    System.out.println("getTag - Nome da Tag: " + name);
    Tag aux;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        aux = Tags.get(i);
        i++;
    } while (!aux.TagName.equals(name) && i < Tags.size());
    if (aux.TagName.equals(name)) {
        if (aux.TagInfoTipo.equals("Int")) {
            value = Integer.valueOf(aux.TagInfo);
            return value;
        } else if (!aux.TagInfoTipo.equals("Int")) {
            return null;//add throw exception
        }
```

I just dont know if this is possible in Java, so that n in this example would end up with an int of value 1700.

Comment: You can use generics, however you cannot use primitive types are not currently supported in generics in Java so you would have to use Integer instead of int.

Comment: It is possible, why not.

Comment: Maybe possible, but the 2nd parameter doesn't make much sense, though. It's just there to allow method overloading.

Comment: I will have a look at the generics

Answer (score 0):

For `Java8` you can use lambdas:

**Find Tag instance by it's name:**

```
private static final Function<String, Tag> GET_TAG_BY_NAME = name -> {
    for (int i = 0, size = Tags.size(); i < size; i++) {
        Tag tag = Tags.get(i);

        if (tag != null && tag.TagName.equals(name))
            return tag;
    }

    return null;
};
```

**Definitions how to extract required type:**

```
public static final Function<Tag, String> STRING = tag -> tag != null && "String".equals(tag.TagInfoTipo) ? tag.TagInfo : null;
public static final Function<Tag, Integer> INTEGER = tag -> tag != null && "Int".equals(tag.TagInfoTipo) ? Integer.valueOf(tag.TagInfo) : null;
```

**getTag() method (one for all possible return types):**

```
public <T> T getTag(String name, Function<Tag, T> checkType) throws Exception {
    return Optional.ofNullable(GET_TAG_BY_NAME.andThen(checkType).apply(name))
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Tag name '" + name + "' was not found"));
}
```

**Client code:**

```
String strTag = getTag("name", STRING);
Integer intTag = getTag("name", INTEGER);
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will give a look as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

C does not have "call by reference" (in contrast to C++, which does have *true* call by reference). In C, something similar is often emulated using `void*` pointers, but this is often not really a good practice.

From the description in the question, it seems like there is nothing special about the task at hand: Just implement the necessary methods...

```
float getTag(..., float t) { ... }
int   getTag(..., int   t) { ... }
long  getTag(..., long  t) { ... }
```

And they will be separate methods, in C as well as in Java. (Even though, technically, you can pull off some [nasty tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617133/3182664) and push the limits of either language...)

---

However, the task that you described appears occasionally, and from the code that you posted, can probably be summarized as follows:

**You want a place where you can generically store objects of different types, and retrieve the objects by giving them a *name* and some *type information*.**

There are some possible solutions for that, and they can be implemented in a type-safe and concise way in Java: You can just pass the expected type to the method, and make sure that the returned object matches this type.

This also covers the case of converting an `Integer` object into a primitive `int`, via auto-unboxing. However, some care has to be taken in this case, in order to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Here is a complete example, showing the **very** basic structure of such a "type safe storage". Of course, this could be extended arbitrarily, but should be enough to get the point across:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class GenericTypeSafeStorage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Container container = new Container();

        container.put("Nome", "Ricardo");
        container.put("Horas Jogl", "1700");
        container.put("Frutas", "Bananas");
        container.put("Horas", 1700);

        String nome = container.get("Nome", String.class);
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);

        // This could throw an exception, but here, just returns null:
        Integer nomeInteger = container.get("Nome", Integer.class);
        System.out.println("Nome as integer: " + nomeInteger);

        int horas = container.get("Horas", Integer.class);
        System.out.println("horas: " + horas);

        try
        {
            // Careful: This returns an Integer that is null, and trying
            // to convert it into an "int" will cause an exception!
            int frutasAsInt = container.get("Frutas", Integer.class);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException expected)
        {
            System.out.println("Expected");
        }

    }
}

class Container
{
    private final Map<String, Object> elements;

    Container()
    {
        this.elements = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    public void put(String name, Object element)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(name, "The name may not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(element, "The element may not be null");
        elements.put(name, element);
    }

    public <T> T get(String name, Class<? extends T> type) 
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type, "The type may not be null");
        Object element = elements.get(name);
        if (element == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Class<?> actualType = element.getClass();
        if (type.isAssignableFrom(actualType))
        {
            return type.cast(element);
        }
        return null; // Or throw something:
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        //    "There is no element with name " + name + " and type " + type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will give a look as soon as I can!