# Why return type of same-named-method should be same in sub-class Java?

Tags: java

My background is C++. I know what is overloading and what is the overriding.
I want to ask if I don't want to override the method from the parent and want to make my own method with different return type and same name, why java not allowing me to do this?

Example:

```
class X{
    public void k(){

    }
}
public class Y extends X{
    public int k(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Why java not applying hiding concept here? mean class Y should hide X's method. what is the reason behind?

C++ applying Hiding concept.

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public:
        void k(){
            std::cout << "k from A";
        }
};
class B:public A{
    public:
        int k(){
            std::cout << "k from B";
            return 0;
        }
};
int main(){
    B obj;
    obj.k();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it? For example you loose the possibility tu create virtual functions.

Comment: @Lasoloz Why Java not allowing to change return type. I know if I declared function virual in C++ then I need to be same return type ( But why? ) same question for Java why return type should be same?

Comment: I know this is old, and you may already have an answer (though you haven't accepted any answer to this question), but just to clarify: Say you have a class `Foo` with a method `List<String> getValues()`. Then you have a class `Bar` which extends `Foo` and "overrides" the `getValues()` method but changes the return type to `Set<String>`. Now, if you program to an interface (as is typical) you might have `Foo foo = new Bar()`, but if you call `List<String> values = foo.getValues()` you have a problem... everything says a `List<String>` should be returned but you end up with a `Set<String>`—oops.

Answer (score 4):

Because all methods in Java are "virtual" (i.e. they exhibit subtype polymorphism). C++ also disallows conflicting return types when overriding virtual member functions.

```
struct Base {
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int f() override { return 0; }
};
```

Compiler output:

```
8 : error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual int Derived::f()'
int f() { return 0; }
^
3 : error: overriding 'virtual void Base::f()'
virtual void f() {}
^
```

Note that only *conflicting* return types are disallowed. Different return types are allowed, as long as they are *compatible*. For example, in C++:

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* f() { return nullptr; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived* f() override { return nullptr; }
};
```

And in Java:

```
class Base {
    Base f() { return null; }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    Derived f() { return null; }
}
```

Comment: can you give me any example about java where it could cause the problem?

Comment: @UnKnown Hiding is generally considered bad practice, as it can be confusing to users of a class who expect the base class function to be called. However, I have realized my answer was wrong. I have updated it with the correct reason!

Comment: Joseph I already know about C++. but what's about Java? why java not allowing?

Comment: Because all methods in Java are virtual :) Did you want to know why both C++ _and_ Java disallow hiding of virtual functions?

Comment: Yes Please, I just was expecting the parent's Reference should call the child Object's method why it considering return type during calling? can you explain?

Comment: @UnKnown Just updated my answer. Incidentally, virtual functions _can_ be hidden, just not by changing the return type (because the return type of a virtual function can vary in derived classes).