# Why doesn't sumBy(selector) return Long?

Tags: kotlin

[sumBy(selector)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) returns Int

[sumByDouble(selector)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by-double.html) returns Double

Why doesn't sumBy return Long? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: the decision was to go with "the least surprise", which is always Int

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's a decision Kotlin team made. Since it's [not possible to have return type overloads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744511/java-why-no-return-type-based-method-overloading) the `sumBy*` have to have different names depending on the return type.

It's easy enough to add your own `sumByLong` though:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumByLong(selector: (T) -> Long): Long {
    var sum = 0L
    for (element in this) {
        sum += selector(element)
    }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: IMO it should be in stdlib

Comment: `var sum: Long = 0.0` does not compile, I've changed it to `0L`

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still learning Kotlin, so I had to go read up on extension functions.  Is there a convention on where these should be placed in a project?

Comment: I'm typically placing them in file named after the receiver class e.g. `Iterable_.kt` but I've seen `Iterables.kt` also.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the `sum()` extension function which does have a `Long` variant, in conjunction with `map()`

```
val totalLength = files.map { it.length() }.sum()
```

Or you could wrap this into an extension function, though I don't see much benefit over the inline version:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumByLong(selector: (T) -> Long): Long {
    return map { selector(it) }.sum()
}
```

Comment: Its a little more expensive than miensol's solution

Answer (score 7):

Optionally you can use `fold` function.

```
val totalLength = files.fold(0L) { acc, it -> acc + it.length() }
```

It's not much longer than `sumBy` code.

Comment: that should be the best ans

Answer (score 1):

As of [Kotlin 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#a3d6dc8c), you can use [`sumOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html), which resolves the type based on the return type of the function argument:

```
// prints 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647
println((0..30).sumOf{ 1 shl it })    

// prints -1 due to 32-bit overflow
println((0..31).sumOf{ 1 shl it })

// prints 2^32 - 1 = 4294967295 because it works with 64-bit longs
println((0..31).sumOf{ 1L shl it })
```

[Try it in the Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/k1yX4pUKR)