# Overload with different return type in Java?

Tags: java, overloading

Why is it not possible to overload a function just by changing the return type?  Will that change in a future version of Java?

By the way, just for reference, is this possible in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function overloading by return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: KNU, the other answer differs in that it asks the question in general, non-language specific terms. Also interesting is that other question's accepted answer goes further by specifying that the Java JVM does allow it to be done with manipulation of internals.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can't do it in Java, and you can't do it in C++. The rationale is that the return value alone is not sufficient for the compiler to figure out which function to call:

```
public int foo() {...}
public float foo() {..}

...
foo(); // which one?
```

Comment: I always thought that if we did something like int i = foo() or float f = foo() it would know which one, but if the statement is just the function that it the compiler wouldn't know. I get it know. Thanks.

Comment: @nunos even if it was float f = foo() the compiler wouldn't be able to figure it out because both an int would be valid input for an float. Compare float f = 7; (is 7 a float or int?)

Comment: @NomeN But your statement suggests that func(int i) and func(float i) would be indistinguishable for the compiler - and we all know this is not true. The real reason is given by Oded (see next answer) - it's about the method's signature. And, btw. 7 is definitely integer while 7.0 or 7f is float ;-)

Comment: 7.0 is not `float`, it's `double`.

Comment: @erlord & @FredOverflow I am only trying to say that the compiler could choose either the float-foo or int-foo without being illegal, thus not being able to choose. That parameters are handled more strictly does not detract from my point. And of course 7 by itself is definitly an integer, but I was hinting at implicit conversion here. In my example 7 would be converted to a float, although it is an integer, at runtime it would 'become' a float.

Comment: but what if this is valid scenario. For example I have `Class1 method1(Class2,Class3)`. Then I need overload which utilizes above method, obtain say another representation from returned value and returns it, say `Class1.getClass4()`. So I will have `Class4 method2(Class2 p1, Class3 p2){return method1(p1,p2).getClass4();}`. Isnt this valid scenario? I have to have method with different name: `Class4 method1ReturnAsClass4(Class2, Class3)`

Comment: The fact that `foo();` without a return type would be ambiguous is not necessarily a reason to disallow it as an overload. There are arguments that can cause ambiguity (e.g. `foo(null);`), but that doesn't make the overload inherently invalid.

Comment: It is possible with Wrapper classes but not with primitive data types.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is superficial and not finished. The example call must be like this, of course:
`int result = foo();`

Answer (score 56):

The reason is that overloads in Java are only allowed for methods with different *signatures*.

The return type is not part of the method signature, hence cannot be used to distinguish overloads.

See [Defining Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) from the Java tutorials.

Comment: But why is the return type not part of the **signature**

Comment: @andho - Because that's how signatures have been defined?

Comment: oh "just because"! I see.

Comment: Return type IS a part of method signature. Just look into class disassembly.

Comment: It really isn't @konmik - not by the rules of method overloading. Try it. Same method name, same parameter types in the same order, different return types. Won't compile.

Comment: Yes it will not compile, but NOT because return type is not a part of signature.

Comment: Yes, because *the return type is not part of the signature*. The signature is - the name of the method + the types and order of its parameter. Read the link I've provided in my answer: "The signature of the method declared above is: `calculateAnswer(double, int, double, double)`". See that the return type is not included, @konmik.

Comment: It seems the referenced links states this multiple times, the last line says `The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.` so it looks the return type is part of the declaration but no the signature !

Comment: In fact overloading methods are two different methods in a class with the same name but different arguments

Answer (score 24):

Before Java 5.0, when you override a method, both parameters and return type must match exactly. In Java 5.0, it introduces a new facility called covariant return type. You can override a method with the same signature but returns a subclass of the object returned. In another words, a method in a subclass can return an object whose type is a subclass of the type returned by the method with the same signature in the superclass.

Comment: I was baffled when I first saw this. Thanks for explaining why this is possible!

Comment: overloading and overriding are different. Overloading does not (necessarily) involve inheritance

Comment: This answer may sound misleading for a newbie in Java, because it's not relevant with **overloading** at all, it's **overriding** - completely other thing.

Answer (score 9):

`Overloaded` methods in java may have different return types given that the argument is also different.

Check out the sample code.

```
public class B {
    
    // Method to be overloaded
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    //This will work
    public StringBuilder greet(String name) {
        return new StringBuilder("Hello " + name);
    }

    //This will not work
    //Error: Duplicate method greet() in type B
    public StringBuilder greet() {
        return new StringBuilder("Hello Tarzan");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: basically the return type is not taken into account, only the arguments, sad but true

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

Answer (score 1):

Return type does not matter while overloading a method. We just need to ensure there is no ambiguity!

The only way Java can know which method to call is by differentiating the types of the argument list. If the compiler allowed two methods with the same name and same argument types, there would be no way to determine which one it should call.

Comment: Of course, the compiler can easily distinguish which overloaded function to call based only on the return value. Thus `int result = foo();` is not the same as `float result = foo();`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

If you are aware of function execution then you will be aware that when we call a function the definition part executes and at last we require the return statement, hence we can say return comes after the function's whole defintion, thats why if there are two or more functions with same name and with same type and no. of arguments then at the time of calling how compiler will know about which one to be called, because function name and parameters are the same. At the time of calling firstly all the focus will be on arguments and function name and after the completion of function definition at last we deal with return statement.

Compile Time Error is better than Run Time Error. So, java compiler renders compiler time error if you declare the same method having same parameters.

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer? (Also the reason it is a compile time error is because the compiler can't figure out which method to call, so how is it supposed to generate the proper executable code)

Answer (score 1):

The overloaded method is a completely different method from any other method of the same name. Overloading is not much more than name reuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int division(int a, int b){
   int result = a/b;
   return result;
}
public double division (float a, float b){
   double result = a/b;
   return result;
}
```

i am pretty sure that in java 8

it is ok

Comment: Here the method signature(list of parameter types) are different.

Answer (score -4):

no not really possible that way you can only overload by no of arguments or data type of the arguments