# interface: php vs java

Tags: java, php, interface, double

I notice something very different between java and php on interface, when you create the same methods in their interfaces.

PHP:

```
interface Visitor 
{
    public function visit(Visitable $Visitable);
    public function visit(Visitable2 $Visitable2); // this is wrong in php.
}
```

Java:

```
interface Visitor 
{
    public double visit(Visitable Visitable);
    public double visit(Visitable2 Visitable2); // this is ok in java
}
```

you can look at the check it out on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pL4mOUDi54o) at 3:35 for java.

how come java allows that? what does `double` do anything? and no `double` in php?

Comment: double is a return type for the method.

Comment: PHP doesn't allow method overloading in classes, Java does.... PHP !== Java

Comment: Note that return type hinting is planned for PHP7 - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/returntypehinting

Comment: that's will be cool! looking forward to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java actually allows **overloading**: this means that you can have a method with the same name but with two different signature.

In the case of Java there are two methods with the same name `visit` in overloading:

1. one accepts a param of type `Visitable`;
2. the other `Visitable2`.

You cannot do that in PHP because PHP doens't support overloading.

Also please notice that `double` (the method return type) in that case does nothing. The return type alone [cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439782/overload-with-different-return-type-in-java) to achieve overloading as the compiler/interpreter has no way to know which implementation to bind in some circumstance.

Comment: thanks. that's will be cool if php is going to support that in the future!