# Overload error?

Tags: java, overloading, bluej

The below is my current code. I have to create a system of arrays that returns the averages of some random numbers through the use of overloading for my Java class. However, when I compile, BlueJ tells me that there is a "method myAverage(int []) is already defined in class overload" error, and I do not know what to do in order to fix it.

Thanks!

```
/**
 * Write a description of class overload here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class overload
{
private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone)
{
     int sum = 0;

     for(int i=0; i < arrayone.length ; i++)
     {
         sum = sum + arrayone[i];
     }
     double average = sum / arrayone.length;

     return average;
}

private static int myAverage (int [ ] arraytwo)
{
     int sum = 0;

     for(int i=0; i < arraytwo.length ; i++)
     {
         sum = sum + arraytwo[i];
     }
     double average = sum / arraytwo.length;

     return average;
}

public static void main (String [ ] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter any number below.");
    System.out.print("Enter the integer here:  ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();

    int [] arrayone = new int [x];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++)
   {
       arrayone[ i ] = (int)(Math.random( ) * 100) + 1;
    }


    myAverage(arrayone);

    System.out.println("\n\nThe average of the first array is :  " + average);

    System.out.println("\n\nEnter any number below.");
    System.out.print("Enter the integer here:  ");
    int y = scan.nextInt();

    int [] arraytwo = new int [y];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraytwo.length; i++)
   {
       arraytwo[ i ] = (double)(Math.random( ) * 100) + 1;
    }

    myAverage(arraytwo);
}
}
```

Comment: You have two methods with same signature `private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone)`

Comment: The two methods have slightly different signatures.

Comment: @arsb48 No they don't. The variable name isn't part of the method signature. Both are just `int myAverage(int[])`.

Comment: @arsb48 first learn what is method overloading then start write a program.

Comment: This assignment is due in 32 minutes.

Comment: The teacher never really taught us, he gave us a quick overview and expects us to try to figure it out by ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "method myAverage(int []) is already defined in class overload" error

You have two methods with same signature

```
private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone)
```

Just remove any one. And change the `return` type to `double` since you are returning `average` of type `double`.

```
private static double myAverage (int [ ] arrayone)
```

---

> I do not understand what you are saying

In your case, this is not a method overloading. Method overloading means

1.Methods `return` type must be different.

ex:

```
private static double myAverage (int [ ] arrayone){ 
                ^
}

private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone){
                 ^   
}
```

2.Number of arguments must be different.

ex:

```
private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone){
                                        ^
}

private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone, int [ ] arraytwo){
                                        ^                  ^
}
```

3.Type of arguments must be different.

ex:

```
private static int myAverage (double [ ] arrayone){
                                 ^
}

private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone){
                                ^
}
```

Either of these one must be true.

Comment: The thing is, however, is that the second method has a signature of '(private static int myAverage (int [ ] arraytwo)', not '(private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone)'. I will change the second method so it reads "double" instead of "int", but I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: is method overloading possible in java by changing the return type of method?

Comment: I don't really know, I've only been coding Java for a few months. This is for an AP class, but this is my first experience with overloading.

Comment: I understand, thanks.

Comment: Satya how could you do method overloading in java by changing only method return type ? read this [Overload with different return type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439782/overload-with-different-return-type-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to overload the method in java

1. By changing number of arguments
2. By changing the data type

[Method Overloading in Java](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java)

`private static int myAverage (int [ ] arrayone)` and `private static int myAverage (int [ ] arraytwo)` both have same datatype `int` and same number of parameter,you have to change datatype of one method.

Answer (score 0):

@Satya is right.

I will try to explain in more detail.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

> Overloaded methods are differentiated by the number and the **type** of
>   the arguments passed into the method. In the code sample, draw(String
>   s) and draw(int i) are distinct and unique methods because they
>   require different argument types.
>
> You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the
>   same number and **type** of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell
>   them apart.
>
> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating
>   methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature
>   even if they have a different return type.

@arsb48 you two method in same signature. Argument name is not counted as overload

```
private static int **myAverage** (**int [ ]** arrayone)
private static int **myAverage** (**int [ ]** arraytwo)
```

So that you only need to keep one method to do the job

```
private static int **myAverage** (**int [ ]** array)
```

The point 2 @Satya advice to change return type to double is to improve the quality of result

```
int[] array = [1,2];
myAverage(array); //This will return 1 instead of 1.5 because convert double/float to in will lost precision.
```

Below is the sample:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class overload
{
private static double myAverage (int [ ] array)
{
     int sum = 0;

     for(int i=0; i < arrayone.length ; i++)
     {
         sum = sum + arrayone[i];
     }
     double average = sum / arrayone.length;

     return average;
}

public static void main (String [ ] args)
{
double average;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter any number below.");
    System.out.print("Enter the integer here:  ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();

    int [] arrayone = new int [x];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++)
   {
       arrayone[ i ] = (int)(Math.random( ) * 100) + 1;
    }


   average = myAverage(arrayone);

    System.out.println("\n\nThe average of the first array is :  " + average);

    System.out.println("\n\nEnter any number below.");
    System.out.print("Enter the integer here:  ");
    int y = scan.nextInt();

    int [] arraytwo = new int [y];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraytwo.length; i++)
   {
   arraytwo[ i ] = (double)(Math.random( ) * 100) + 1;
}

average = myAverage(arraytwo);
    System.out.println("\n\nThe average of the second array is :  " + average);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Think about it,

You create an object of overload

Like new overload(); // Use Camel Case for Class names in java.
then after you make a call on

new overload().myAverage([1,2,3]);// How will the compiler know which method you are calling,

Another concept is for variable arguements in java where it looks for backward compatibility.