# Problems caused by generics and inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

```
interface A1<T> {
    fun f1(t: T)
}
class B1 : A1<Any> {
    override fun f1(t: Any) {
    }
}
interface A2<T: String>: A1<T> {
    fun f2(t: T)
}
class B2 : B1, A2<String> {
    override fun f1(t: String) {
    }

    override fun f2(t: String) {
    }
}
```

> B2 error: Type parameter T of 'A1' has inconsistent values:Any,String

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to inherit from same generic interface twice (with separate types) in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528261/any-way-to-inherit-from-same-generic-interface-twice-with-separate-types-in-ko)

Comment: There are some similarities

Comment: You cannot have two functions f1(t: *) because of type erasure.

Comment: There are some similarities
In java, this is fine
`interface A1<T>{
        void f1(T t);
    }
    static class B1 implements A1{

        @Override
        public void f1(Object o) {

        }
    }
    interface A2<T extends String> extends A1<T>{
        void f2(T t);
    }
    static class B2 extends B1 implements A2 {
        @Override
        public void f2(String s) {

        }
    }`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, in java, this is not possible too

Comment: Is not only re-implementation of the A2 interface can solve this problem