# Why doesn't `out` allow a generic Kotlin interface to be specialized in child classes?

Tags: kotlin, generics, recursive-templates

I have the following two classes in a new body of Kotlin code:

```
open class Parent {
  open fun f(a : Double) : Parent {
    TODO("Implement")
  }
}

class Child : Parent() {
  override fun f(a : Double) : Child {
    TODO("Implement")
  }
}
```

The child class is legally overriding the parent's implementation of `f` in this case. The argument type is the same, and the return type is allowed to be child of the return type given in the parent.  So far so good.

I also have an existing code base that has an interface and many implementations of that interface that have this pattern:

```
interface F<out T> {
  fun f(a : Double) : T
}

class Uncle : F<Uncle> {
  override fun f(a : Double) : Uncle {
    TODO("Implement")
  }
}
```

I would like to make the new code work with the existing code base by having `Parent` and `Child` implement the interface `F`, but I'm stuck.  If I make `Parent : F<Parent>` that is fine for the parent, but then I'm not allowed to have `Child : Parent(), F<Child>` because `Child` now has inconsistent values for the parameter to the interface `F` according to the compiler.  If I make `Parent : F<Parent>` and don't specify an interface explicitly for `Child : Parent()`, then the child class doesn't quite have the same behavior as expected in some cases because this doesn't capture the "sameness" of the return type on `f` for instances of the child class.

For a general pair of classes and an interface without `out` on the parameter, this problem is expected and ultimately related to type erasure. (See [Any way to inherit from same generic interface twice (with separate types) in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528261/any-way-to-inherit-from-same-generic-interface-twice-with-separate-types-in-ko) and [Kotlin class that implements generic interface twice (with different types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479261/kotlin-class-that-implements-generic-interface-twice-with-different-types) .)

My situation is more specific though.  *If it were allowed*, I would have `F<Child>` is effectively a subclass of `F<Parent>` due to the use of `out`. (See [What is out keyword in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298702/what-is-out-keyword-in-kotlin) .)  I don't think the type-erasure argument holds for this case.

So two related questions:

1. Is there an underlying reason that this cannot be supported (like the type-erasure argument for the general case)?
2. Is there a good work-around?

Comment: Ohh, interesting. It looks like a valid case indeed.

Comment: You’re describing a “self” type. Some languages have it, but unfortunately Java and Kotlin do not.