# Generic Interface inheritance

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a set of **component *interfaces***

```
interface ITest<I> {
    operator fun invoke(p: I)
}

interface OTest<O> {
    operator fun invoke(): O
}

interface IOTest<I, O> {
    operator fun invoke(p: I): O
}
```

and a corresponding **functional *interface***

```
interface TestAdder<T> {
    fun add_f(p: T) {}  //default impl
}
```

that gets inherited to add the components from above to respective **(functional) collection *interfaces***

```
interface ITestSet<I> : TestAdder<ITest<I>> {
    val i_v: I
    
    fun i_f1(p: I) {}  // default impl
    fun i_f2(p: I) {}  // default impl
    fun i_f3(p: I) {}  // default impl
}

interface OTestSet<O> : TestAdder<OTest<O>> {
    val o_v: O
    
    fun o_f1(p: O) {}  // default impl
    fun o_f2(p: O) {}  // default impl
    fun o_f3(p: O) {}  // default impl
}

interface IOTestSet<I, O> : TestAdder<IOTest<I, O>> {
    val i_v: I
    val o_v: O
    
    // same as ITestSet<I>
    fun i_f1(p: I) {}  // default impl
    fun i_f2(p: I) {}  // default impl
    fun i_f3(p: I) {}  // default impl 
    
    // same as OTestSet<O>
    fun o_f1(p: O) {}  // default impl
    fun o_f2(p: O) {}  // default impl
    fun o_f3(p: O) {}  // default impl

    fun io_f1(p: I): O
    ...
}
```

---

So far, so unnecessay: ideally `IOTestSet<I, O>` should inherit the functionality defined in `ITestSet<I>` and `OTestSet<O>`:

```
interface IOTestSet<I, O> : ITestSet<I>, OTestSet<O>, TestAdder<IOTest<I, O>> {
    fun io_f1(p: I): O
    ...
}
```

but obviously the `TestAdder<T>` *interface* introduces inconsistency within the inheritance chain.

---

*This smells like an age-old, archetypal paradigm (and probably even an XY) problem, still it seems I have to ask:*

##### Q: How to compose this inheritance chain?

###### Or what is the established/much better/less and not unnecessarily convoluted/more elegant design pattern?

Comment: So what type of thing is the `add_f` method of `IOTestSet` going to take? `ITest<I>`, `OTest<O>`, or `IOTest<I, O>`? If you want overloads for all  types to exist, inheritance won't work here because, (long story short) type erasure.

Comment: @Sweeper ya, the idea is to have an overloaded `f_add` function on all `[IO|I|O]TestSet` interfaces accepting their respective `IO|I|O]Test` interfaces. I guess I could externalize the `[i_|o_}f<n>` functionality into yet another set of Interfaces, inherit them and have a specific `add_f` method on all `TestSet`s. Any other way you can think of to redesign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for why this doesn't work, it is because you are inheriting from the same interface, just with different type arguments. And the reason why you can't do *that* is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35528261/5133585).

## Composition

When inheritance doesn't work, we can try composition. (See also: "[Prefer Composition Over Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/5133585)")

Rather than having `ITestSet` and `OTestSet` inherit `TestAdder`, which is the root cause of your "inheriting from the same interface but with different type arguments" problem, add get-only properties of type `TestAdder` to `ITestSet`, `OTestSet`, as well as `IOTestSet`.

Then `IOTestSet` will be able to inherit `ITestSet` and `OTestSet`. The full code is as below:

```
// I have added variance modifiers where appropriate
interface ITest<in I> {
    operator fun invoke(p: I)
}

interface OTest<out O> {
    operator fun invoke(): O
}

interface IOTest<in I, out O> {
    operator fun invoke(p: I): O
}

interface TestAdder<in T> {
    fun add_f(p: T) {}  //default impl
}

interface ITestSet<I> {
    val i_v: I
    val inputAdder: TestAdder<ITest<I>>
    fun i_f1(p: I) {}  // default impl
    fun i_f2(p: I) {}  // default impl
    fun i_f3(p: I) {}  // default impl
}

interface OTestSet<O> : TestAdder<OTest<O>> {
    val o_v: O
    val outputAdder: TestAdder<OTest<O>>
    fun o_f1(p: O) {}  // default impl
    fun o_f2(p: O) {}  // default impl
    fun o_f3(p: O) {}  // default impl
}

interface IOTestSet<I, O> : ITestSet<I>, OTestSet<O> {
    val ioAdder: TestAdder<IOTest<I, O>>
    fun io_f1(p: I): O
}
```

## Implementing the interfaces

From what I can see, you can still implement this new set of interfaces in the same way as you did before - e.g. to implement `ITestSet<String>`, you just do:

```
class Foo: ITestSet<String> {
    override val i_v: String = "Some String"
    override val inputAdder = object: TestAdder<ITest<String>> {
        // implementation goes here...
    }
}
```

Note that it is possible to provide a default implementation for `inputAdder`:

```
interface ITestSet<I> {
    val i_v: I
    val inputAdder: TestAdder<ITest<I>> get() = object: TestAdder<ITest<I>> {
        // implement your thing here...
    }
    ...
}
```

but this recreates the object every time you access `inputAdder`, which may not be the semantics you intended.

This brings me to another difference of this design, compared to your original design: you allow implementations to implement `inputAdder`, `outputAdder`, and `ioAdder` in whatever way they like. This means that they are not necessarily implemented so that e.g. each `ITestSet` always has the *same* `inputAdder`, like in your original design, where the "inputAdder" of each `ITestSet` is always *itself*. Of course, this isn't a problem if you have total control over the code.

Comment: Because I want those three `TestSet` interfaces to represent individual types as well, as clean as possible, I just went for a third set of functional interfaces - but your approach is likely the more idiomatic design pattern, and overall great advice. Thanks for the thorough snswer!