# Methods with the same signature but different return type in two interfaces

Tags: java

I have two interfaces :

```
interface S {
    public String m1();
}

interface O {
    public Object m1();
}
```

I decide to implement both O and S in a class Test :

```
class Test implements O, S {

}
```

My question :

Why must I only implement the method `public String m1()` and not the other ?
And secondly, why can't I implement `public Object m1()` instead of `public String m1()` ?

Comment: I found an answer that might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type

Comment: An interface is a promise. Returning a `String` fulfills the promise to return an `Object`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Lets say your Test is allowed to implement `public Object get(){...}` and inside that method you `return new Person("Adam"); }` (Person extends Object so it is acceptable result for such method). Now imagine that somewhere else there is a method like `method(S s){ String value = s.get(); }`. So it expects `S` so we can pass `Test` instance since it implements `S`. But at `String value = s.get();` instead of expected `String` we got an `Person`. Would that be OK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java allows you to use *covariant return types* for overriding methods.

This means that an overriding method can return a subtype of the type declared on the overridden method.

In this case, `String` is covariant with `Object`; since all `String`s are also `Object`s, it is a suitable return type for implementing `O.m1()` *and* `O.m2()`.

But you can't have two methods with the same signature in a single class (return type isn't part of the signature). So you can only implement at most 1, when the return types are compatible, as here. (And if they are not compatible, you'd get a compiler error).

Comment: And as for the first part of the question, see [Overload with different return type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2439782/2402272)

Comment: @AndyTurner *return type isn't part of the signature* for `javac`, not `JVM` and AFAIK kotlin somehow leverages that

Comment: @Eugene return type is part of the method signature in the JVM. But we're talking about Java here, not byte code, not Kotlin.

Comment: @AndyTurner right, this is entirely correct, I gave a plus one btw, just that `kotlinc` does use this in a very weird way IMO, I am working on a question this entire week for this...

Answer (score 0):

`String` is instance of `Object` Class. So when you are implementing interface method you can change type conversion. Only **primitive type** like `int,double..and others` are not able to type conversion.

Comment: How about autoboxing int to Integer?

Comment: U can use primitive types with autoboxing also. You can change type conversion with Wrapper object of primitive type.  But not with primitive type.

Comment: Well every int ist an Integer, so also an object. But not every Integer is an int as Integer and every other object is nullable unlike primitives

Answer (score 0):

you may use this

```
class Test implements O, S {

    O  _o = new O() {
              @Override
              public Object m1(){
                return new Object();
              }
           };

    @Override
    public String m1(){
      return "";
    }
}

Test t = new Test();
t.m1();// m1 from s
t._o.m1();// m1 from O
```

Comment: Can you explain quickly how the first declaration works or provide me a link which explain it ? (O _o = new O() and then open brackets & close them with ";", that's the first time I see this)

Comment: @Spn that is an anonymous inner class in java which is used as instance variable of class Test