# must two overloading methods have same return value, to be called "overloading"?

Tags: java

[image: by oracle]

Oracle people said, they must do so, but I just feel weird...

```
package com.xenoamess;

public class Main {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public long add(long a, long b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

For example, CAN'T we call the two functions above "overloading"? and if can't, why?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439782/overload-with-different-return-type-in-java

Comment: The methods you have wrote in your questions are "overloaded". What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Progman I think the point is that the return types are different

Comment: The return types can be different. There is no requirement that they have to be the same type.

Comment: @Progman Exactly, now see the screenshot by OP in the question above, claiming that they need to be. That is what is confusing XenoAmess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> CAN'T we call the two functions above "overloading"?

We *can* call it overloading, because the methods have different parameter types.

In the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9), overloading is defined as:

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

"Override-equivalent signatures" basically means "same signatures when type erasure is taken into account" (Learn more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)).

The signature of a method doesn't include the return type:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

---

I think what the question in the screenshot was getting at, is that you can't overload methods by *only* changing the return type. I would say the options are worded rather badly.

Answer (score 1):

same functions headers with different parameters is called overloading , so I think your example is overloading .

and i think it's about the headers only not the return type .