# the return value of an instance method called by superclass reference are incompatible with the declared return type

Tags: java

```
public class Confusion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F f = new S();
        //System.out.println(f.test().a); //from papa string a
        //f.test().pb();//from son
        AnotherSon as = f.test();//Incompatible types. Found: 'com.solution.day10.AnotherFather', required: 'com.solution.day10.AnotherSon'

    }
}

class F {

    AnotherFather test() {
        System.out.println("from father");
        return new AnotherFather();
    }
}


class S extends F {
    @Override
    AnotherSon test() {
        return new AnotherSon() ;
    }
}

class AnotherFather{
    String a ="from papa string a";
    public void pb(){
        System.out.println("from papa");
    }
}

class AnotherSon extends AnotherFather {
    String a = "from son string a";
    public void pb(){
        System.out.println("from son");
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `test` method in `class S` overrides its superclass' method with changing the return type from AnotherFather to AnotherSon which is subclass as defined.

var `f` is declared as type of `F` but assigned to an instance of `Son`.  `f.test()` should run the `test()` code in `class S`,as indeed it is ,if you debug the program.

Since `test()` of `class S` is executed, it's natural thing to use type of `AnotherSon` to get the result. But I get the `Incompatible types`. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overload with different return type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439782/overload-with-different-return-type-in-java)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp no but thanks

Comment: `F f` is "everything" the compiler knows about `f`. It knows that `f` holds a reference of type `F`. So if you call `f.test()` it checks what `test` on `F` could return and sees `AnotherFather`. So `f.test()` is guaranteed to return an object of type `AnotherFather`. You try to assign that to a variable of type `AnotherSon`. That's not valid, because not every instance of `AnotherFather` is also an instance of `AnotherSon`. Basically: if you want this to work, don't define your variable as being of type `F`, use `S` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In class `S` you are returning the child class and in class `F` you are returning the base class. So when you call `f.test()` it only knows about `AnotherFather`. The return type `AnotherSon` cannot be resolved from `AnotherFather`. It would have worked the other way round.