# Why cannot c# or c++ differentiate methods based on return type?

Tags: c#, c++, return-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

If I have two methods:

```
myClass mc = new myClass();

double d = mc.GetPoint();
int i = mc.GetPoint();
```

Why cannot the C# or C++ compilers differentiate these functions from their return type? I would have though the return type would be part of the signature of the method, just like any method arguments are.

Why can't the compilers handle this?

Comment: How would you then expect `var x = mc.GetPoint();` to work for C#, or `auto x = mc.GetPoint();` for C++?

Comment: Just being part of the signature does not make it (the return type) eligible for selecting a particular overload -- there are other design factors to consider.

Comment: I saw C# creator Anders Hejlsberg asked this question. He pointed out that it's not always as simple as `result = function(x)`. What if the result is being passed to another function which is *also* overloaded, e.g. `DrawPoint(mc.GetPoint());`? Ultimately, this feature could never work in every situation, and would only provide questionable utility anyway.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to base function calls on return types. What would happen if you ignored the return value? For example `int x = foo();` vs `MyType x = foo();`. What about just `foo();`?

Answer (score 1):

C# supports dynamic typing like when you use `var`.  How then is the compiler supposed to know which method it should call?

Comment: While this is a valid argument (+1), `var` is *not dynamic typing*. `var` simply allows the C# compiler to apply some *very basic type inference* to determine a *static type* without having to be explicitly told what the type is. (This is very crucial for the operation of LINQ and anonymous types.)

Comment: This is true, but there are more fundamental issues (without bringing in `var`). C++ had this restriction well before the `auto` keyword meant 'please infer this type' :)

Comment: In such cases the compiler could ask the programmer to explicitly declare the return type.