# Ambiguous call error, both functions have different return types

Tags: c#, overloading

I have two overloaded methods, both called FunctionX. One of them returns a Boolean object, and one a predefined class called Logs.

The error I'm getting is: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'FunctionX(string)' and 'FunctionX(string)'.

In one of my other methods, I call FunctionX(string), expecting the Log object, but it's throwing this error. I thought the compiler was supposed to look at the return type and figure this out for itself. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While languages like Perl and Haskell **do support** overloading by return type, function overloading by return type is not supported by most statically typed languages. So, it is better if you do not make this trivial problem a part of your code.

**Added**:

You can find more answers in an earlier Stackoverflow discussion here:

[Function overloading by return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: Foudnd this question on SO, after I had posted mine. Will mark your answer as the right one so people can find it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have more then one function using the same signature e.g.

```
string Function1(bool t)
int Function1(bool t)
```

You need to call each function different names, or having different params e.g.

```
string Function1(bool t)
int Function1(bool t, int g)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload a method to have different return types.  How would the compiler know what to call here?

```
string Foo() { /* ... */ }
int Foo() { /* ... */ }

object f = Foo();
```

Language designers need to take *all* circumstances into account, not only those that are most trivial.

Comment: Another example is two methods that return `void` having identical signatures.

Comment: what if it was int f = Foo(); wouldn't it be obvious then?

Comment: @Freakishly: Yes, but for that simple case there are plenty of non-trivial cases that would require exceptions.  As Eric Lippert would say, every feature has a cost.  Its cost in complexity, testing, documentation, etc.  must be weighed against the utility of the feature.  I would argue that overloaded methods returning different types is not all that useful, and it becomes much less useful when you have to impose a bunch of restrictions upon it.  Just not worth it, so it isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for the compiler to distinguish between functions with the same method signature except for the return type.  And as far as I know no compiler can that is strongly typed. You must change the signature in some way.  On option is to use a generic function and provide the return type.

Answer (score 1):

The return type does not partecipating on overloading in C#.

You can, for example:

1. Declare separate functions `FunctionXToLog` and `FunctionXToBool`
2. `FunctionX(string s, out Log logobject)`, `FunctionX(string s, out bool value)`

Just to give you a hint.

Comment: thanks, this actually helps more than the "no, you cannot!" answers :P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two function with the same signature only differing in return value!

Comment: Why are you yelling at the OP? :)

Comment: @EdS. it wasn't my intention to yell. Maybe I used the exclamation mark by accident. I'm a non native speaker ... unfortunately german :-)

Comment: Well, my girlfriend is of German descent (a few generations back though, born in the US) and she loves the language, so I don't know that it's unfortunate.  Usually we don't use exclamation points unless we are *really* trying to convey a yell or some sort of agitation.  It doesn't really matter, Danke Shun for great chocolate and cars ;)

Comment: It's quite all right chaps, I didn't take the exclamation as offensive or anything! :)

Answer (score 0):

The signature of a method is its name and the types of its parameters - only. Its return type is *not* part of its signature.

Hence the problem you are having, since the two methods have identical signatures. The compiler does not use the return type, or the type of the object being assigned to, to determine which method to call.

You will have to specify the classname of the method you want (assuming that the two methods are in different classes). Or you will have to provide another parameter for one of the methods, to give it a different signature. Or, finally, you will have to rename one of the methods to make them unambiguous.