# How to return a template container (i.e. vector, list, array) in a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, std

I have the following class:

```
class Conversion {
//...
public:
    template<class T,
        template<class, class = std::allocator<T>> class> T doTheWork()
    {
        //do the work
        return {};
    }
};
```

which I want to copy the content to a sequencial container (vector, list, deque), which are declared as:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
```

And I getting confused about the template declaration.
Considering I want to have the receiver as the following examples, how should I declare `copyContentToContainer`?

Examples:

```
int main() {
    Conversion conv;
    std::vector<std::string> container1 = conv.doTheWork();
    std::list<int> container2 = conv.doTheWork();
    std::deque<double> container3 = conv.doTheWork();
}
```

Comment: you can use the trick used in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165847) where you would return a proxy type with a templated conversion operator

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specify the element type and container type separately, you can

```
template<class T, template<class, class = std::allocator<T>> class C> 
C<T> doTheWork()
{
    //do the work
    return {};
}
```

then

```
std::vector<std::string> container1 = conv.doTheWork<std::string, std::vector>();
std::list<int> container2 = conv.doTheWork<int, std::list>();
std::deque<double> container3 = conv.doTheWork<double, std::deque>();
```

Otherwise, you can just

```
template<class T>
T doTheWork()
{
    //do the work
    return {};
}
```

then

```
std::vector<std::string> container1 = conv.doTheWork<std::vector<std::string>>();
std::list<int> container2 = conv.doTheWork<std::list<int>>();
std::deque<double> container3 = conv.doTheWork<std::deque<double>>();
```

BTW: Template parameters can't be [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) from return type. They can only be deduced from function arguments. So you have to specify them explicitly.

> When possible, the compiler will deduce the missing template arguments from the function arguments.

If you don' want to write them twice, you can apply `auto` (since C++11).

```
auto container1 = conv.doTheWork<std::vector<std::string>>();
auto container2 = conv.doTheWork<std::list<int>>();
auto container3 = conv.doTheWork<std::deque<double>>();
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to avoid here is the type explity when calling the method `conv.doTheWork<std::vector<std::string>>();`

Comment: The template arguments either have to be explicitly stated, or they must be deduced. The template arguments can be deduced from function parameters, and since C++17 from constructor arguments. Finally, you can define a default type, if the type isn't given. But the compiler needs to know the type from _somewhere_ if it's going to instantiate that class.

Comment: @anc Answerd revised.