# if return type is different .. then it will be overloading or over riding

Tags: c#, oop

```
public int Add(int a, int b) 
public float Add(int a, int b)
```

returned type is different.

is this overloading or overriding ?

and what if access type is different

```
public int Add(int a, int b) 
private int Add(int a, int b)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What if I call the method without retrieving the return value .. which one will be called ?

Comment: Who is stopping you from typing this and trying it out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's neither: it's invalid code. You *can't* create two methods which differ only by return type. (Or by return type and access modifier...)

If you could, it would be overloading though - overriding happens *across* the inheritance hierarchy, where a method in a derived class overrides a virtual method declared in a base class. In this case, you've given no indication that they're in different classes.

The biggest difference between overloading and overriding is when the decision is made about which method to use: the compiler picks the signature based on the *compile-time* types, and then the implementation is chosen based on the *execution-time* type of the actual object.

So if method `Derived.M(int)` overrides `Base.M(int)`, then the compiler doesn't care - it just knows it's calling `Base.M(int)` and lets the CLR take care of the virtual dispatch.

However, if there are methods `Foo.M(int)` and `Foo.M(float)` then the compiler decides *at compile-time* which of those will be used. (Of course, they could be virtual with overrides involved as well.)

It's worth noting that overloading across an inheritance hierarchy can be interesting, too - I've got a whole [article about overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) which lists some of the oddities you might come across.

Answer (score 3):

**Neither**. It's a compile-time error:

```
error CS0111: Type 'Foo' already defines a member called 
'Add' with the same parameter types
```

Neither return type nor access type is a part of method signature.

Comment: I don't think it's OK to say that the "return type is not part of method signature".

Comment: @ken2k Indeed its [Ok to say so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is neither!

You can't do that because the parameters need to differ. Just different return types don't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal in C#, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type), two similar functions returning different types is called overloading in other languages (Perl, for example).

As for having different access modifiers, I do not know if any language supports that. C# certainly doesn't.