# Overloading by return type

Tags: c++, overloading

I read few questions here on SO about this topic which seems yet confusing to me. I've just begun to learn C++ and I haven't studied templates yet or operator overloading and such.

Now is there a simple way to overload

```
class My {
public:
    int get(int);
    char get(int);
}
```

without templates or strange behavior? or should I just

```
class My {
public:
    int get_int(int);
    char get_char(int);
}
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function overloading by return type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442026/function-overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: @AdamV, I really like your comment. Short but completely solid.

Comment: @Adam V Actually there is already such ambiguity with taking the address of an overloaded function. In such case there should be some type expectation of the expression. In case there isn't one the program is ill-formed. And this is already implemented. I don't think it'll be very hard to use the same rules for implementing function overloading by return type. So in your concrete example ambiguity will be removed with a cast of the returned type. Instancing with `int` return value will look like this `(int)get(9)` and with `char` like this `(char)get(9)`.

Comment: When you reach here, I think the best choice it to think of a two different function names like suggested by Luchian.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

No there isn't. You can't overload methods based on return type.

Overload resolution takes into account the **function signature**. A function signature is made up of:

- function name
- cv-qualifiers
- parameter types

And here's the quote:

**1.3.11 signature**

> the information about a function that participates in overload
>   resolution (13.3): its parameter-type-list (8.3.5) and, if the
>   function is a class member, the cv-qualifiers (if any) on the function
>   itself and the class in which the member function is declared. [...]

**Options:**

1) change the method name:

```
class My {
public:
    int getInt(int);
    char getChar(int);
};
```

2) out parameter:

```
class My {
public:
    void get(int, int&);
    void get(int, char&);
}
```

3) templates... overkill in this case.

Comment: You can't overload a normal function on return type, but the compiler will choose between conversion operators based on the resulting type; you can leverage off this to create a proxy which effectively acts as if you'd overloaded on return type.

Comment: I'm now reading about templates. Could you please make an example of it here? Doesn't `My<char> var; var.get(3);` work in this case?

Comment: @JeffPigarelli The template solution means member templates: `My::get<T>(int)`.  It's a valid alternative __if_ 1) you have to handle a lot of different types, all with the same basic code (e.g. `boost::lexical_cast<T>( someStringValue )`, or you have to be able to call these functions from some other template (`myMy.get<T>( i )`, where `T` is an argument of this other template.  Otherwise, as Luchian says, they're overkill.

Comment: Note that the *reason* you can't overload based on return type is that C++ lets you discard the value of a function call. So if you simply called `my.get(0);` the compiler would have no way to decide which piece of code to execute.

Comment: @benzado in that case, it should throw compiler errors only in such cases, otherwise it should deduce the type like it does in *so* many other scenarios already.

Comment: @rr- Should it? If you feel that way, you look into the bondage-and-discipline languages, like Standard ML.

Comment: @benzado for the same reasoning `void foo(int x = 0) {}
void foo(double x = 0) {}` should be disallowed. However, it is not. Only in the case where the compiler really cannot distinguish (`foo()`) you'll get an error

Answer (score 91):

It's possible, but I'm not sure that it's a technique I'd recommend for
beginners.  As in other cases, when you want the choice of functions to
depend on how the return value is used, you use a proxy; first define
functions like `getChar` and `getInt`, then a generic `get()` which
returns a Proxy like this:

```
class Proxy
{
    My const* myOwner;
public:
    Proxy( My const* owner ) : myOwner( owner ) {}
    operator int() const
    {
        return myOwner->getInt();
    }
    operator char() const
    {
        return myOwner->getChar();
    }
};
```

Extend it to as many types as you need.

Comment: +1, although a corner case, the conversion operator is actually overloaded on return type, and can be leveraged to get this feature about everywhere.

Comment: @MatthieuM. About everywhere, but with the usual caveats concerning implicit conversions.  You do run the risk of introducing ambiguities that wouldn't otherwise be there.  In the case of a Proxy, however, I think the risk is minor---you're not going to have instances of the Proxy type other than in the case where you want the implicit conversion.  Note too that the conversion in the proxy counts as one user defined conversion.  If you need `std::string`, and the proxy only offers `operator char const*()`, it's not going to work.

Comment: why use proxy here, I can't think of any cases where proxy is a must. Can you provide one? thanks!

Comment: @ChenLi Because conversion operators are the only way to resolve functions based on return types, which means you have to have a proxy to convert.

Answer (score 16):

As stated before, templates are overkill in this case, but it is still an option worth mentioning.

```
class My {
public:
    template<typename T> T get(int);
};

template<> int My::get<int>(int);
template<> char My::get<char>(int);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't overload by return type; only by parameter types, and const/volatile qualifiers.

One alternative would be to "return" using a reference argument:

```
void get(int, int&);
void get(int, char&);
```

although I would probably either use a template, or differently-named functions like your second example.

Comment: a la EFI API where the return type is an `int` error code.

Comment: Be careful, char and int types can be implicitly converted.

Comment: If using a template, you'd probably have to explicitly supply the type in angle brackets when you use it, right?  Because in so many circumstances the compiler wouldn't be able to know an exact type you are treating it as?

Comment: Hmmm fabda01's answer seems to have a solution to that but I don't understand how it works

Answer (score 9):

You can think this way:

You have:

```
  int get(int);
  char get(int);
```

And, it is not mandatory  to collect the return value of the function while invoking.

Now, You invoke

```
  get(10);  -> there is an ambiguity here which function to invoke.
```

So, No meaning if overloading is allowed based on the return type.

Answer (score 9):

Resurrecting an old thread, but I can see that nobody mentioned overloading by ref-qualifiers. Ref-qualifiers are a language feature added in C++11 and I only recently stumbled upon it - it's not so widespread as e.g. cv-qualifiers. The main idea is to distinguish between the two cases: when the member function is called on an rvalue object, and when is called on an lvalue object. You can basically write something like this (I am slightly modifying OP's code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class My {
public:
    int get(int) & { // notice &
        printf("returning int..\n");
        return 42;
    }
    char get(int) && { // notice &&
        printf("returning char..\n");
        return 'x';
    };
};

int main() {
    My oh_my;
    oh_my.get(13); // 'oh_my' is an lvalue
    My().get(13); // 'My()' is a temporary, i.e. an rvalue
}
```

This code will produce the following output:

```
returning int..
returning char..
```

Of course, as is the case with cv-qualifiers, both function could have returned the same type and overloading would still be successful.

Comment: For context, what is actually happening here is normal function overloading on the hidden `this` parameter (`this&` vs `this&&`).

Answer (score 3):

While most of the other comments on this problem are technically correct, you can **effectively** overload the return value **if** you combine it with overloading input parameter.  For example:

```
class My {
public:
    int  get(int);
    char get(unsigned int);
};
```

DEMO:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class My {
public:
    int  get(         int x) { return 'I';  };
    char get(unsinged int x) { return 'C';  };
};

int main() {

    int i;
    My test;

    printf( "%c\n", test.get(               i) );
    printf( "%c\n", test.get((unsigned int) i) );
}
```

The resulting out of this is:

```
I 
C
```

Comment: that completely changes the function signature so you are not overloading by return type, you are simply overloading

Comment: I used this method successfully to return a variety of values for a C++ JSON API running production.  Worked great!

While technically not overloading by return type, it accomplishes the intent of different return types with the same function name, is valid and clear C++, and has little overhead (a single variable instantiation in the function call).

Comment: Though this is not overloading by return type, it does the job. makes me say "sneaky"

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to overload by return type in C++. Without using templates, using `get_int` and `get_char` will be the best you can do.

Comment: Just to be sure: Something like `template <class T> T get(int)` would work?

Comment: Yes, @Niklas, but you'd have to call it as `get<int>` or `get<char>`, which doesn't really gain you much over `get_int` and `get_char` if you're not also using other template features.

Comment: @Rob: Well, the compiler can determine `T` if you have something like `T get(T)`. If you call `get('a')`, the compiler deduces that `T` is a `char` and you don't have to explicitly call `get<char>('a')`. I'm still not sure if this is standard, although I think it is. FYI, both GCC and Clang support this.

Comment: That's perfectly standard, @Netcoder, but it's not a case of the compiler deducing just the return type, which you suggested was possible. In your example, the compiler deduces the argument type, and once it knows that, it fills in the value of `T` everywhere else, including the return type. I expected you to give an example of the compiler deducing `T` for the function in Niklas's first comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload methods based on return types. Your best bet is to create two functions with slightly different syntax, such as in your second code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can't overload a function based on the return type of the function. 
you can overlead based on the type and number of arguments that this function takes.

Answer (score 0):

I used James Kanze's answer using a proxy:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569120/262458

I wanted to avoid using lots of ugly static_casts on a void*, so I did this:

```cpp
#include <SDL_joystick.h>
#include <SDL_gamecontroller.h>

struct JoyDev {
    private:
        union {
            SDL_GameController* dev_gc = nullptr;
            SDL_Joystick*       dev_js;
        };
    public:
        operator SDL_GameController*&() { return dev_gc; }
        operator SDL_Joystick*&()       { return dev_js; }

        SDL_GameController*& operator=(SDL_GameController* p) { dev_gc = p; return dev_gc; }
        SDL_Joystick*&       operator=(SDL_Joystick* p)       { dev_js = p; return dev_js; }
};

struct JoyState {
    public:
        JoyDev dev;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    JoyState js;

    js.dev = SDL_JoystickOpen(0);

    js.dev = SDL_GameControllerOpen(0);

    SDL_GameControllerRumble(js.dev, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 300);

    return 0;
}
```

Works perfectly!