# A quick c++ query

Tags: c++, string, class, function, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type)

Why can't I declare three member functions like this:

```
  void x(int a);
  void x(String a); 
  int x(String a);
```

?

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you can't overload by return type.

```
void x(string a)
```

and

```
int x(string a)
```

have the same signature. The signature is made of:

- function name
- parameters
- cv-qualifiers

Which, in your case, are the same.

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not allow you to overload functions based on the return type. Function overloading is only allowed based on the type of the arguments. This means that `void x(String a)` and `int x(String a)` are seen as the same function as far as overloading rules are concerned.

One important case that may be confusing (but is often used) is when `const` is put at the end of a member function. That would look something like `int number_of_peanuts(bool tasty_only) const`. That `const` at the end means that the class that this member function is part of cannot be modified by this function.

However, this is actually just a special case of argument type overloading. When you have a member function that is not declared `static`, there is implicitly an extra parameter added to your function, this `this` pointer. This means that the example function I gave is roughly equivalent to `int number_of_peanuts(Class const * this, bool tasty_only)`. If you didn't have `const` at the end of the function, then instead it would be like `int number_of_peanuts(Class * this, bool tasty_only)`.

So to summarize, the type and number of arguments are the only thing that allow you to overload. If you pass by value, as in `void x(int a)`, then `const` won't give you overload opportunities, because the outside world cannot tell the difference between whether you modify your copy or not. If you pass by reference or pass a pointer, then you can use `const` with the thing they are referring to as overload options, so `void x(std::string & a)` and `void x(std::string const & a)` are different, because the world can tell if you modify a or not. Putting `const` at the end of the function is another source of overload opportunity. And finally, and most obviously, `void x(int a)` and `void x(int a, int b)` is a legal overload because you have a different number of arguments.

Comment: cv-qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`) are already included in my answer. For instance, `void x(String const & a)` and `void x(String & a)` are different because the argument types are different. If you are talking about member-function `const`, so `void x(String a) const`, then that is also a special case of argument-type overloading. The `const` at the end means that the implicit `this` parameter (the pointer to the class, which is implicitly passed as the first argument to the function) is a `MyClass const * this` instead of a `MyClass * this`.

Comment: A cv-qualifier applied to the function modifies the function signature. The fact that under-the-hood it converts this to a const pointer is an implementation detail.

Comment: I agree with you, but a beginner (which the OP obviously is) might not find it so clear, so pointing it out in the actual answer might be very helpful.

Comment: Actually it changes how the function is used. For instance, try using a member function with `bind`. If you attempt to bind `int` to the first argument of the function, you'll get a very long and confusing compiler error message. I'll edit to emphasize this point.