# Output only overloading c++

Tags: c++, function, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type)

Is it possible to overload only the output of a function. Say for example i have a function that can return a pose in two different ways. A 6DOF pose or a homogenous transform matrix. So i would have two functions:

```
Eigen::Vector6f pose();
```

and

```
Eigen::Matrix4d pose();
```

Is it ok to overload the only the output?

If I do then how will the compiler know which function to use?

Can it tell when I do this:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d poseHolder = pose();
```

To use the second function? If not is there a way to accomplish this without just having separately named functions?

Comment: In computer programming the "output of a function" is known as the "return type of a function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't normally do this. If you really insist on using the same name for two different functions, you can kind of fake it by returning a proxy object with overloaded conversion operators:

```
struct Proxy {
    operator Eigen::Vector6f() const {
        // ...
    }

    operator Eigen::Matrix4d() const {
        // ...
    }
};

Proxy pose() { return Proxy(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded functions **must** differ by their signature. For plain functions, the return type is not part of the signature so you cannot do what you're after. For function templates though the return type is part of the signature so you can overload function templates that differ only by return type.

The rules are logical. Indeed, for normal functions, the compiler (in the general case) would have no idea which function to call. In case of function templates, the caller is free to specify the return type explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The key to function overloading is a function’s argument list, also called the ***function signature***.

If two functions use the same number and types of arguments in the same order,
they have the same signature; the variable names don’t matter. C++ enables you to define
two functions by the same name, provided that the functions have different signatures.

The
signature can differ in the number of arguments or in the type of arguments, or both.

Take your sample, if just you dont' want to store return value of `pose();` then which one should be called?

```
pose();
```