# Return variant type from method

Tags: c++, templates, trailing-return-type

So I have a resource manager that is basically a dictionary of void* objects that have some metadata describing their type (basic metadata like a string). I have a template method right now that returns an object:

```
class ResourceManager
{
    template<typename Type>
    Type RetrieveResource( Text name );
};
```

My question is how can I make this method *not* a template method? I've done some research into trailing return types and using that funky syntax. The idea is that at some point I have the data as the correct type and I want to return it as that type without additional casting on the end user's part.

I'm shooting for something like this:

```
auto RetrieveResource( Text name)
{
    return _dictionary[ name ]; // There's more to this, but imagine it returns varying type objects.
}
```

I've given some thought to implementing a Boost::Any type of object, but it's kind of complicated (not that I'm lazy). I'm trying to avoid template syntax on the end user's part.

Any help would be great. Also I cannot use Boost library structures like variant or any (project specs). Thanks in advance!

I understand I'm kind of asking for magic here, but I figured that's what S/O is for: finding magic. If it's not possible, I understand. But if someone has an innovative solution, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that would be to ambiguous. You [can't overload by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type) and you can't use `auto` as the return type.

Comment: Yeah, that's about where I am. Thanks for the link to a relative post.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, you could do something like this, assuming that every `Text` key corresponds uniquely to a resource with a known, different `Type`:

```
class BaseText
{
    // constructors that take const char *, std::string, etc.
    // .. whatever else you currently have in class Text
};

template<typename Type>
class Text : public BaseText
{
   // constructors that take const char *, std::string, etc.
};
```

Then change `ResourceManager` to be:

```
class ResourceManager
{
    template<typename Type>
    Type RetrieveResource( Text<Type> name );
};
```

Note this still requires compile-time polymorphism, but means that as long as your user can obtain the correctly-typed version of `Text<Type>`, they can use it to obtain the correctly typed resource without having to explicitly provide the `Type` argument again, so it'll look like a normal function call.

This works easily if the set of possible `Text<Type>` objects can be statically declared and initialized with the right types, which I'm not sure is true in your case.  If, instead, the user must be able to create them at runtime, though, they'll need to know the correct type to create, so it just pushes the problem back a bit further: however, it might be convenient enough if the same `Text<Type>` object is going to be used over and over again.

Note that you're also out of luck if you or the client need to store different `Text<Type>` objects together in some kind of data structure, since that will require some sort of type erasure (i.e. upcasting to `BaseText`). So this is somewhat of a specialized solution but it's possible it could be useful, depending on how things are structured (I really can't know without seeing more of your code).

**EDIT**: As per the comment below, it seems like the type of the object is determined by the client when they insert an object, so you could possibly do something like this:

```
class ResourceManager
{
    BaseText PutResource( const BaseText& name, BaseResource& resource );

    template<typename Type>
    Text<Type> PutResource( const BaseText& name, Type& resource );

    BaseResource& RetrieveResource( const BaseText& name );

    template<typename Type>
    Type& RetrieveResource( const Text<Type>& name );
};
```

So the client is required to hold on to the unique typed key object in order to retrieve the resource later; if they choose to type erase it by upcasting it back to `BaseText`, then they'll be responsible for recovering the type information correctly, either by downcasting the key before retrieval or downcasting the resource afterwards.

Note that this is just an extra option on top of what you will have to do anyway: if you want to provide access to resources using a non-type-specific key, the only way to do so is by returning a non-specific resource type (i.e. `BaseResource`, `boost::any`, `boost::variant<...>`, or one of their moral equivalents.) However, creating a type-specific subclass of `BaseText` allows you to obtain a correctly typed resource, using the exact same syntax (i.e. with no explicit template parameter required). Furthermore, this allows the following usage:

```
// tree is a resource of type `Tree`
auto key = manager.PutResource("Tree01", tree);

// ...

const BaseText& basekey = key; // lose type information

// ...

// these are all equivalent
Tree& tree = dynamic_cast<Tree&>(manager.RetrieveResource("Tree01"));
Tree& tree = dynamic_cast<Tree&>(manager.RetrieveResource(basekey));
Tree& tree = manager.RetrieveResource(key); // no casts required
Tree& tree = manager.RetrieveResource<Tree>("Tree01")
```

The `dynamic_cast` versions are basically what you'll need to do without these templated overloads, but the others two versions are extra options on top of that that you can use with this approach without any runtime cost.

Comment: I appreciate the help but unfortunately I cannot key the type to a given identifier. The identifiers are not related to the types until the object is added to the collection. It's not a call like RetrieveResource( "Object" ), it's used like RetrieveResource( "Tree01" ).

Comment: @WilliamCustode take a look at my new edit in case that helps. it's basically no worse than using a type-erased variant type, except that it hides the type-erasure behind a type-safe interface as long as the client is able to keep the correctly typed key (if they can't, then you're in the same boat as you are now.)

Comment: I fear I may have miscommunicated the nature of the key. The key is just a string name of the object used to pull it later. There's no typical relationship between the key and the object (other than the obvious fact that it's used to retrieve the object). Unfortunately the solution you've provided does not get me any further than I already am. I appreciate your efforts though! Upvote for effort and relativity.

Comment: @WilliamCustode sure, just making sure though, isn't it at least guaranteed that the same type of object you put in with a given key is the same type you want out? with this solution the client could do something like `auto key = manager.PutResource("Tree01", tree)` and later do `Tree tree = manager.RetrieveResource(key)` without any casting; if they have to use the non-type specific key then they can use the non-templated overload (which is basically the same thing as what you'll have to do anyway, otherwise.)

Comment: `BaseText` can just be a thin wrapper over a string and implicitly convertible to/from it, just like (presumably) in your current case, `Text<Type>` would just be a type-specific derived class without any new members.

Comment: Yes, but the syntax would be auto tree = RetrieveResource<Tree>( "Tree01" ). It's the template syntax I don't want to expose to the user.

Comment: And the overload that returns a boost::any violates the terms; I'm not allowed to use the boost libraries, as stated in the post.

Comment: @WilliamCustode `boost::any` is just an example, presumably you're going to have to do something like that anyway to support type erasure. I'm just saying you can have a templated overload and a non-templated one, that's all. You don't need `RetrieveResource<Tree>( "Tree01" )` as long as you're ok with `BaseResource resource = RetrieveResource( "Tree01" )` (which is what you're going to have to do anyway) but you get `Tree tree = RetrieveResource(key)` (without templated syntax, naming the type, or casting) if key is typed as `Text<Tree>`.

Comment: @WilliamCustode so it's an extra option on top of whatever solution you're going to have to do anyway, but it means that a key object can be reused to get a typed resource multiple times without naming the type each time or using template syntax. anyway, it's fine if that's not useful, but just making sure you understand since it doesn't seem clear. (Also, with `auto` on the client side, they'll never have to name the `Text<Tree>` type either, as long as they're not forced to type-erase it.)

Comment: @WilliamCustode I updated the answer a last time, just to make things clear--just making you understand that this is an extra option that doesn't affect the basic required approach

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the best choice will be returning some base class pointer. The minus is that you force anyone to derive from it, but with smart architecture of base class there could be more pluses

Comment: Thanks; there is already a fairly strong typing system involved. But there's no way for the system to consciously cast data for the user, which is the goal.