# Overriding a base class function with different return types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a base class named Variable:

```
class Variable
{
protected:
    std::string name;   
public:
    Variable(std::string name="");
    Variable (const Variable& other);
    virtual ~Variable(){};
};
```

I have several derived classes, such as Int, Bool, String etc. For example:

```
class Bool: public Variable{
private:
    bool value;

public:
    Bool(std::string name, bool num);
    ~Bool();
    Bool (const Bool& other);
    bool getVal();
```

Each derived class has a method named getVal() that returns a different type (bool, int, etc.). I want to allow polymorphic behavior for Variable class.
I tried: `void getVal();` which seemed wrong and the compiler showed an error: `shadows Variable::getVal()` which sounds bad.
I thought of using `template <typename T> T getVal();` but it didn't help.

Any suggestions? Do I have to use casting for that?

Many thanks...

Comment: Show what you tried in the base and derived class

Comment: `Variable condition = condition_statement.evaluate(type);`
//Where `condition_statement.evaluate(type)` returns a Bool object
`cout << condition.getval();`

Compiler says:"‘class Variable’ has no member named ‘getVal’"

Comment: Note that you can only have **covariant return types** while overriding functions else you will end up hiding the base class function, which is not the behavior you want.

Comment: How `cout` should know what type to print?

Comment: It was just an example... `condition.getVal()` should return bool. But it can also be a string or int or folat. It depends on the type of the Object. getVal() of Bool returns bool, getVal() of Int returns int etc.
I want the ability to create a method getVal() in class Variable that would be overridden by the getVal() of the derived classes.

Comment: I understand what you want `getVal()` to return. The question is how you can use the returned value. Once you answer that, you will see that you either cannot use `getVal()` at all, or you don't need it to be virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can't overload by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568890/493122). I think that a template would work better in your case. There's no need for polymorphism or inheritance here:

```
template<class T>
class Variable {
protected:
    T value;
    std::string name;   
public:
    Variable(std::string n, T v);
    Variable (const Variable& other);
    virtual ~Variable(){};
    T getVal();
};
```

The usage would be [pretty simple](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e04734373c9112a):

```
Variable<bool> condition("Name", true);
Variable<char> character("Name2", 'T');
Variable<unsigned> integer("Name3", 123);
std::cout << condition.getVal() << '\n';
std::cout << character.getVal() << '\n';
std::cout << integer.getVal() << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I need that the different derived classes (e.g. Bool, String, Int, Float and others) will have different operator overloading behavior. Let's say I need Int to override operator+ and eventually add the values, but Bool should throw an exception if Bool+Bool is attempted. How do I do that using templates?

Comment: @Shakedk, that's not a problem. Just use [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Comment: Looks a bit complicated, but I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The types are determined in compile time. So no amount of polymorphism will allow you to change the return type.
Virtual dispatch is done at runtime, but the types of the methods and object must be correct and the same in compile time.

If you just need to print the value, just add virtual ToString() method. Or even make i templated if you don't want to write it again for each derived type.