# How to replace a method return type?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

This is just a learning experiment for fun. I'm toying with `bytecode` manipulation.

I'm just messing around for learning with `asm` in `java`. I wonder if it is possible to replace the return type of a method from an interface.

Let's say that I have an `interface`:

```
interface Modifiable {
    Integer a();
}
```

Should I create a copy of the class, load it into the `class loader`, and then modify this new interface?

If it were possible, this change would be available in compile time? So to speak, that my `ide` autocomplete those new methods.

Comment: It's not working as far as I know

Comment: I believe you cannot overload a return type.  This C++ question might offer you some insight on a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type

Comment: Why downvote, as I explicitly say in the question this is a learning experiment.

Comment: How is this a duplicate, this is just a learning experiment on bytecode manipulation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the return type without changing the interface itself.

Comment: It is a viable option to create a new interface out of that one and then modify over the copy?

Comment: @ssedano how is that different to modifying the existing interface?

Comment: As I said, it is for just for learning. I could then create a class out of that interface.

Comment: if you create a second interface that extends the first one no. if it does not extend the first one then yes.

Comment: @ssedano You can create a class from the original or the copy.  Making a copy doesn't change anything AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the interface itself.

It´s not possible to change the return type of a Method at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the return type to Boolean. Is this possible?

You can change the text from `Integer` to `Boolean`.

You can do this at runtime, but it would make the interface unusable unless all the implementations were changed.

> Should I create a copy of the class, load it into the class loader, and then modify this new interface?

If you like, but I don't see the point.

> If it were possible, this change would be available in compile time?

Yes, change the word from Integer to Boolean. Much easier to do in your IDE.

Comment: @ssedano looks more like idle curiosity than learning purposes.

Comment: @ssedano Unless there is a reason to do this in which case I can suggest an alternative, there doesn't appear to be any reason to do this.  Just because you can do something doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In compile time you definitely cannot change the return type of a method. And in runtime, yes it is possible. But that is not a good idea at all. Below guide line from asm, might help you

You must either return the replacement method/field when you visit the original one using a ClassVisitor, or you must first remove the original method/field in the ClassVisitor (see "[1. How do I remove a method/field?](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q1)"), and then add the new method/field by calling a visit method on the ClassWriter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is just an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is that who ever is using the Object that implements Modifiable will be expecting an Integer to be returned when that method is called.  You are breaking a promise that has been made by the creator of this interface.

You could of course create your own class that extends the type being returned by the interfaced method.  I do not recommend this for something like Integer, because there will be many ways Integer may be used but it is technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know, it can't be done at runtime.
but you can use generics to do that.

in your example, do it like

```
interface Modifiable<T> {
    T a();
}
```

where T will be your type.