# Why does non-const method hide const overload?

Tags: c++, reference, overriding, constants

Given the code below:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(): value( 0 ) {}

    int* get()
    {
        return &value;
    }

    const int& get() const
    {
        return value;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const int& ref_value = a.get();
}
```

results in the following compilation error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:23:35: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'
      const int& ref_value = a.get();
                                   ^
```

It seems that the overloaded get() method with const modifier does get ignored completely and the compiler sees only the non-const definition of it. It is somehow understandable since the a object is not constant. One solution would be to make the *a* object constant. Though there are other two solutions that makes the code compileable:

1. Change the signature of the const get() method by different name or other parameters added.

   ```
   int* get();
   const int& get_changed() const; <-- this gets called
   ```
2. Change the non-const get() method to return a reference instead pointer.

   ```
   int& get(); <-- this gets called
   const int& get() const;
   ```

though with

```
int* get();
const int& get() const;
```

we have a compiler error.

What puzzles me is the reason behind all of these behavior.

Comment: Why is it puzzling? Wouldn't it be more or at elast equally puzzling if the `const` method was called on a non-const object?

Comment: Yup, this exactly happens in those two cases I mentioned ( const method gets called on non-const object ), so it is still puzzling.

Comment: If there's only a const method, there is no overload resolution to perform. Only the const method can be called. If there are two overloads, then the non-const gets chosen for a non-const object, and vice versa. I don't find this particularly puzzling.

Comment: Why compiler error for this? Why not choosing the const method for a non-const object instead of giving the compile error?

Comment: Searching for some for info in SO, I found the rationale to be somewhat related to C++ being strongly-typed. Letting return type be part of function signature effectively makes implicit/explicit conversion of return value a disaster. Like a comment here, what if return value is discarded? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type

Comment: @Roland Because the non-const returns a pointer, and you are trying to initialize a reference from that. That is the reason for the compiler error.

Answer (score 5):

When you have both a `const` and non-`const` overload of the same function with the same parameters, which one gets called depends *only* on the `const`ness of the object on which you're invoking the function. So invoking on a non-const `a` *must* call the non-`const` overload.

It's exactly the same situation as this:

```
void foo(int *p);

void foo(const int *p);


int main()
{
  int i;
  const int ci;
  foo(&i);  // Calls the first overload
  foo(&ci);  // Calls the second overload
}
```

A `const`-qualified function *can* be called on a non-`const`-qualified object, but that requires a "nonconst to const" conversion. If there's an overload which doesn't require such a conversion (is a better match), it will be preferred.

Comment: By "parameters" you have just excluded return type as part of signature.

Comment: @user3528438 The signature does not include the return type. At least for non-templates.

Comment: @user3528438 Which is correct (insofar as I never mentioned the word "signature"). Overload resolution does not look at the return type at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza but in the OP, changing "int* get();" to "int& get();" solves the problem. Is there a reason why that works?

Comment: @user3528438 Because it then calls the non-const overload and binds the returned `int&` to the `const int& ref_value`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the compiler can't do overload resolution based on a different return type.

Only the function signature is taken into account for overload resolution. And the function signature consists only of the function name, the parameters, and the cv qualifiers - not the return type.