# Precedence of const member function over return value type match

Tags: c++

In `Y::test1()` a non-const `X::operator void*()` takes precedence over a seemingly better match, `X::operator bool() const` - Why is that? And where is this phenomenon described in the standard?

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  operator void*()      { std::cout << "  operator void*()\n"; return nullptr; }
  operator bool() const { std::cout << "  operator bool()\n";  return true; }
};

struct Y {
  X x;
  bool test1()       { std::cout << "test1()\n"; return x; }
  bool test2() const { std::cout << "test2()\n"; return x; }
};

int main() {
  Y y;
  y.test1();
  y.test2();
}
```

Output:

```
test1()
  operator void*()
test2()
  operator bool()
```

Comment: Related: [how does overloading of const and non-const functions work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5103543/514235) ... and ... [Why does non-const method hide const overload?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28878945/514235)

Comment: @M.M - OK clear thanx! But the dupe is about overload resolution vs. visibility; my question is about the order in overload resolution, so not quite the same (at least neither the dupe nor the other links provided an answer to my question).

Comment: reopened - this question is not about what's in those other questions

Comment: @M.M Why, isn't qualification conversion better than boolean conversion, according to the [ranking of implicit conversion sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: when converting the expression in a `return` statement to the return type of the function, the rules are the same as for initialization (see [conv]/2.4 and [conv]/3).

So we could examime the behaviour of the code using this example instead (with the same `X` as you have, but without `Y`):

```
X test1;
bool b1 = test1;

X const test2;
bool b2 = test2;
```

(in the call `y.test2()`, the type of `this->x` is `X const`, that's what it means to have a const member function).  It would also be the same if we cast to `bool` instead of writing an initialization statement.

---

The part of the Standard dealing with overload resolution in this situation is [over.match.conv], here is the C++14 text (with some elision for brevity):

> **13.3.1.5 Initialization by conversion function [over.match.conv]**
>
> <sup>1</sup> Under the conditions specified in 8.5, as part of an initialization of an object of nonclass type, a conversion function can be invoked to convert an initializer expression of class type to the type of the object being initialized.  [...]
>
> <sup>2</sup> The argument list has one argument, which is the initializer expression. [*Note:* This argument will be compared against the implicit object parameter of the conversion functions. *—end note* ]

The `test2` case is straightforward - a non-const member function cannot be called on a const object, so the `operator void*` is never considered, there is only one candidate and no need for overload resolution. `operator bool()` is called.

So for the rest of this post I will just talk about the `test1` case. The part I elided in the above quote covers that both `operator bool` and `operator void*()` are candidate functions for the `test1` case.

---

It is important to note that **overload resolution selects amongst these two candidate functions**, and it is **not** a case of considering two implicit conversion sequences, each containing a user-defined conversion. To back this up, look at the first sentence of [over.best.ics]:

> An *implicit conversion sequence* is a sequence of conversions used to convert an argument in a function call to the type of the corresponding parameter of the function being called.

We are not converting an argument in a function call here. The rules about implicit conversion sequences come into play when we are ranking candidate functions: the rules are applied to each argument of each candidate function, as we shall see in a moment.

---

So now we look to the rules for *best viable function* to determine which of these two candidate functions is selected. I'll skip [over.match.viable], which clarifies that both of those candidates are viable, and onto [over.match.best].

The key part of that section is [over.match.best]/1.2:

> let *ICSi(F)* denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the i-th argument in the list to the type of the i-th parameter of viable function F. 13.3.3.1 defines the implicit conversion sequences and 13.3.3.2 defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence
>   or worse conversion sequence than another.

Here, `i == 1`, there is only one argument `test1` as explained by [over.match.conv]/2 above -- the argument is the initializer expression `test1`; the "parameter of the viable function" is the implicit object parameter of the member functions of `X`.

*Now* the implicit conversion sequence rules apply:

- `operator void*()` requires no conversion - the argument is `X` and the parameter is `X&`
- `operator bool() const` requires a qualification conversion - the argument is `X` and the parameter is `X const&`

*No conversion* is better than qualification conversion ([over.ics.rank]/3.1.1). So ICS1(`operator void*()`) is a better conversion sequence than ICS1(`operator bool() const`); so at this point `operator void*()` wins ([over.match.best]/1.3).

The subsequent paragraph [over.match.best]/1.4 explains what would have happened if neither of those two sequences was better: we would only then go on to compare the standard conversion sequences from the return type of the candidate function onto the type being initialized.

You can explore this case by changing the `X` member to `operator void*() const`. Now the two ICS1 sequences are indistinguishable as of /1.3, so we go onto /1.4 at which point `operator bool() const` wins because its conversion to `bool` is the identity, whereas `operator void*() const` still requires a boolean conversion.

Comment: I see, thanks. The "***and then***" before [over.match.best]/1.3 is key.

Comment: Technically, not a qualification conversion (that's just pointers) - the relevant tiebreaker is "Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if [...] S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.6.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same
type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers
is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers."

Answer (score 7):

The implicit `this` pointer is non-`const`. So *overload resolution* takes place on the set of *all* non-`const` methods (including templates - which is one for the pub quiz), *before* any `const` methods are considered.

The fact that a function is marked `const` does not ever make it a better fit for a non-`const` `this` pointer, if you get my meaning.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution which largely proxies the standards.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention that says that non-const member functions take precedence over const member functions.

Comment: The `const` methods are viable candidates for overload resolution, but they always lose to non-const methods when the candidates are ranked, in these cases. So I wouldn't use the wording you did in your first paragraph especially.