# This code does not compile due to an unreachable statement

Tags: java

I've tried my utmost to reproduce this in another way, but it seems that only this line gives the error (please excuse the comment):

```
return foo.containsKey(MARKET_DATA) && !foo.get(MARKET_DATA).isMissing();/*mapping code can inject a Missing type*/;
```

However I type this it gives me an error: "unreachable statement". Why is this?

Comment: It's probably due to the extra `;` after the comment.

Comment: Poor Edmund. I don't see this as a particularly poor question, particularly if the IDE highlights the entire line.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's 6x5 reputation from upvotes minus 4x2 reputation loss from downvotes is net 22 reputation increase. The net result isn't so bad. :)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: Yes SO is a funny old world. I'm not convinced my answer is worth 10 * 10 + 15. Especially when you consider that's greater than the score of the excellent answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465404/precedence-of-const-member-function-over-return-value-type-match/39465464 which has more question upvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is clear if you remove the comment:

`return foo.containsKey(MARKET_DATA) && !foo.get(MARKET_DATA).isMissing();;`

Note well the two semicolons at the end: empty statements *are* allowed in Java, but this particular empty statement is *unreachable* as the previous statement *always* `return`s.

(For the avoidance of doubt, a *comment* should not be terminated with a `;`).

Comment: Oh it's that simple? Thank you very much. It's been a long night.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the `;` after the comment:
`/*mapping code can inject a Missing type*/`;

The compiler thinks there is another statement after the return statement. If you delete the `;` after the comment it will work fine (or put it inside the comment).

Comment: Upvoted. Note my edits - do study them to see how you can get the formatting right.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6) `;` is a empty statement. So there is a statement after return