# Using a wrapper class as a pointer to the type it wraps?

Tags: c++, pointers, wrapper

I have a simple wrapper class for Integer types, defined like so:

```
class Integer {
    public:
        Integer() {
        }

        Integer(const int& value) {
            this->value = value;
        }

        int toInt() const {
            return value;
        }

        operator int() const {
            return toInt();
        }

    private:
        int value = 0;
};
```

What I'd like to do, is pass the class above to a function which has a signature like this:
`doSomething(int* value)`

If I were to use a normal int, I could simply do:

```
int value = 5;
doSomething(&value);
```

However, when using the wrapper class I can't since it would use a pointer to the class instead of the actual underlying value.
I know of the address operator `operator&`, which I could use to return a pointer to the value, but it would prevent me from getting a pointer to the class itself if I needed to.

So ideally there would be a way that would allow me to use `&myclass` to get a pointer to the class or the underlying value, depending on what is needed.

Is there such a way?

Comment: Why would you want to implement such class? Is this an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: You can overload `&` but then to get the address of the class you will have to use `std::addressof`. That said, what you are doing is against a good design.

Comment: @Polikdir I've implemented this class so that I can enforce a constant integer size in memory across platforms.

Comment: @Arunmu yes, that's why I'd like to avoid using it.

Comment: This is a built in feature already since C++11 see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: Anyway, I can't see how this class gives you constant size integers.

Comment: @Polikdir the class I've posted is just a quick example I wrote. Anyway, why I'm using the class is outside the scope of the question, and the class is already being used by most of the project we're working on, so changing it isn't an option. It is needed for backwards compatability (the project is was writting with C++03).

Comment: Have you already considered adding a cast-operator to int*?

Comment: @Qub1 C++ already defines cross-platform fixed-sized integer types. See the definitions in the `<cstdint>` header. For example, `int32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I was able to solve my own problem.

I took some inspiration from a comment by @Arunmu and the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569120

By overloading the `operator&()` (address-of) operator and returning a proxy class object, which has implicit conversion operators to pointers of both the type of my original class and the value it wraps I can use the syntax I needed.

I will provide an example for anyone who encounters the same problem:

```
class IntegerPointer {
public:
    IntegerPointer(int& value, Integer& wrapper) : value(value), wrapper(wrapper) {
    }

    operator int*() {
        return &value;
    }

    operator Integer*() {
        return std::addressof(wrapper);
    }

private:
    int& value;
    Integer& wrapper;
};

class Integer {
public:
    Integer() {
    }

    Integer(const int& value) : value(value) {
    }

    Integer(const Integer& value) : Integer(value.value) {
    }

    IntegerPointer operator&() {
        return IntegerPointer(value, (*this));
    }

protected:
    int value;
};
```

This allows you to use syntax such as:

```
Integer test = 5;
doSomething(&test);
```

Where &test can be used as a pointer to the Integer object or as a pointer to the int value it wraps.