# How can I call one [] overloaded operator from the other?

Tags: c++

I have implemented getByte():

```
unsigned char& operator[](size_t i)
{
...
}
```

Now I would like to implement the counterpart getDword() that benefits from the already written char& operator:

```
unsigned int& operator[](size_t i)
{
...
/// call here operator for char& []
...
}
```

How can I achieve that with C++?

I'd like to do something like:

```
char c = x[100]; takes 1 char 
int d = x[100]: takes 4 char from 100 to 103
```

I have seen that you can overload operators by return type (const and non const operator). Its about some magic with *this

Comment: You cannot have a function signature that differs only by return type. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type

Comment: call to opearator [] would be ambigous.

Comment: What is your "getByte" doing? What is your "getDword" supposed to do?

Comment: Just to be clear: "I have implemented getByte():"  No - you've implemented operator[] ...

Comment: As everyone already said, you cannot overload by return type. But you can make operator [] a template. Create an enum, which has 2 types: Byte,Dword, declare template [] function and create 2 specializations, one for Byte, second for Dword.

Comment: I have seen that you can overload operators by return type (const and non const operator). I cannot understand why this linus torvalds does not implemenmtt it in c++11! We are in XIX century for god.

Comment: @S.S It was **never** possible to overload methods by return type. If the return value is not used by caller, how do you deduce which one to call? You can, however, overload methods by their `const`-ness, because then, you can unambiguously deduce which one to call: if the object, on which method was called, is `const` - call `const` method; otherwise - call non-`const` method.

Comment: If the return value is not used by caller, how do you deduce which one to call?. then give a compiler error, that simple it is

Comment: @S.S you can't, so compile fails