# How to invoke this member function in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

Is it possible to call this member `int MyClass::get(int key) const` instead of the `int& MyClass::get(int key)`? In other words, where in the C++ source codes, a value can be used but not a reference?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int input) : i(input) {};
    int i;

    int get(int key) const {
        std::cout << "int get(int key) const " << key << std::endl;
        return i; 
    }

    int& get(int key) {
        std::cout << "int& get(int key) " << key << std::endl;
        return i;
    }
};

void dummy(const int helpme)
{
    std::cout << helpme << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    MyClass abc(6);
    std::cout << abc.get(13) << std::endl;
    int result = (int)abc.get(16);
    dummy(abc.get(18));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have you got an old fashioned cast here `(int)abc.get(16)`?

Comment: In C++17, you will be able to use `std::as_const( abc ).get(...)`. Otherwise, you can bind `abc` to a `const MyClass &`. Note that I do not encourage this kind of design, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a `const &` to your variable. Two simple ways are

```
const auto & abc_const = abc;
std::cout << abc_const.get(13) << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::cout << static_cast<const MyClass&>(abc).get(13) << std::endl;
```

Edit: It looks like you were trying to choose an overload based on the return type, based on these two lines :

```
int result = (int)abc.get(16);
dummy(abc.get(18));
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568890/7359094) explaining how the return type is never used during overload resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I'm looking for