# Why is the return value of the function not part of the symbol name

Tags: c++

The return type is not part of the symbol name. That makes overloading of a function based on the return type impossible. 
What is the idea behind this approach?

Comment: Since you can't overload at all in C, removed the superfluous tag

Comment: Because return type overloading is not allowed

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overloading by return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: It's actually the other way around: overloading on return type is not allowed, so there is no need to encode the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason given by Bjarne Stroustrup as part of a post in newsgroup comp.lang.c++, dated 12 January 1998 is

> The reason that C++ doesn't allow overload resolution based on a return
>   type (so that you need to use explicit qualification in the examples
>   below) is that I wanted overload resolution to be bottom up. For
>   example, you can determine the meaning of a subexpression a+b without
>   considering the complete expression that a+b is part of. Overload
>   resolution can be subtle so even though I knew how to use return types
>   as part of resolution (Ada showed how), I decided not to. As a result
>   of this decision, a+b means the same in a+b+c as in a+b+d.

Agree with it or not, this is the rationale behind the design decision.

Comment: Thanks for finding this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function or method and discard it's return value. How should the compiler figure out what function or method should be called then?

```
int sum(int a, int b)
long sum(int a, int b)

sum(10, 20) // which one should be called?
```

Comment: or `auto result = sum(10, 20);`

Comment: This case could be solved by enforcing an assignmet for all functions with return types

Comment: @dgrat As sander's said, how would you compile `auto result = sum(10, 20);`?

Comment: The problem with auto is somehow self made and got introduced in C++11. I think one could improve the decletype function for cases of ambiguous return types :/

Comment: @dgrat : the point is that adding the return type to the function signature (so it participates in overloading) would invalidate a lot of current code. It would cause more problems than it fixes.

Answer (score 1):

There's a chicken and egg.
Return type isn't considered in overloading rules so isn't part of the function signature.

Although it would appear easy to consider return type in the signature the rules would inevitably become at best complex at worst ambiguous.

Consider relatively harmless looking code like:

```
foo(bar(x),bim(bam(y)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very easy solution to this problem: templates:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(double a, double b)
{
    return static_cast<T>(a+b);
}
```

You call this with `sum<int>(5,6)`, and it'll cast the result to int. This is a bad example, but sometimes this is useful, like the opposite of the famous `std::to_string`, which is called `from_string` (it's not part of the standard), but the return value is of your choice using the template.

You can even have fancier ways to specialize the implementation depending on the type using `type_traits`. In C++11, you can do this:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(double a, double b)
{
    if(std::is_same<double,T>::value) //if the type is double
        return a+b;
    else
        return static_cast<T>(a+b);
}
```

Though you have to cast for every case. To make this fancier (and solve the casting problem, which you'll probably understand only if you start involving strings and other classes with scalar types), in C++17, you can use `constexpr if` and eliminate that problem:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(double a, double b)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same<double,T>::value) //if the type is double
        return a+b;
    else
        return static_cast<T>(a+b);
}
```

In the last branch, the other branch will not make a difference because it'll be evaluated at compile-time. So no casting problems.

Comment: This works, because the parameters are different. Template based overloading just changing the return type will likely also fail :)

Comment: @dgrat I don't understand. What is it that's going to fail?

Answer (score 0):

The others are right that introducing this now would create a lot more problems than it would solve.

It's this way at the moment because it makes logical sense: you say what function (by name) you're going to call, and what arguments you're going to give it; the function is responsible for telling you what you can expect to get back.

Furthermore, being able to call `foo(1, 2)` one way, then `foo(1, 2)` in another way, and get two completely different kinds of results back, would be extraordinarily confusing. It's just… wrong!

We identify a function by what we'll provide to it, not by what it'll provide to us.