# usage of Proxy Pattern of implementing operator overloading by return type?

Tags: c++, proxy-pattern

From [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569120/6949852), @James Kanze show an implementation of operator overloading by return type like this:

```
class Proxy
{
    My const* myOwner;
public:
    Proxy( My const* owner ) : myOwner( owner ) {}
    operator int() const
    {
        return myOwner->getInt();
    }
    operator char() const
    {
        return myOwner->getChar();
    }
};
```

Then I implement my own without proxy:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
const class Czxyl
{
private:
    int a = 1;
    char b = 'c';
    float c = 1.1;
public:
    Czxyl() = default;
    constexpr Czxyl(int a, char b, float c) : a{ a }, b{ b }, c{ c } {}
    constexpr operator int() const { return a; }
    constexpr operator char() const { return b; }
    constexpr operator float() const { return c; }
    Czxyl get() const { return *this; }
    //Czxyl operator() () const { return *this; }
} czxyl;

int main()
{
    int a = czxyl.get();
    char b = czxyl.get();
    float c = czxyl.get();
    std::cout << a << "\n" << b << "\n" << c << "\n";
}
```

I can't figure out why use Proxy?

I know Proxy is a design pattern but still can't think out of any case I have to use such a design pattern here.

Can anyone prove Proxy is a must here using concrete examples?

Comment: It seems kind of pointless to have `T::get()` method that just returns a copy of `T`. Basically, you have `Czxyl` act as its own proxy. The idea behind `Proxy` is that it's small - it doesn't carry around a full copy of the data of its owner.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, but can you explain why it is pointful to return Proxy : )?

Comment: Well, it all starts with the desire to have a method that returns *something* that magically turns into the correct type based on what it's assigned to. `Proxy` is that something. Its point is to delay the computation until the desired type of the result becomes known (the assumption, of course, is that you have a computation that somehow depends on the desired type of the result - this is not a common situation).