# function overloading on operator overloading function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've two similar operator overloading functions, the first return an object, and the second return an char.

```
Cell& operator[](std::pair<int, int> pos) {
  if (pos.first > 0 && pos.first < n || pos.second > 0 && pos.second < n) {
    return Board[pos.first][pos.second];
  } else {
    cout << "Illegal2" << std::endl;
  }
}
char operator[](std::pair<int, int> pos) {
  if (pos.first > 0 && pos.first < n || pos.second > 0 && pos.second < n) {
    return Board[pos.first][pos.second].getCellValue();
  } else {
    cout << "Illegal2" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I call the first one using `board1[{1,2}]='O';` (I have also = overloading function).
the second one I want to use that way: `char c = board1[{1, 2}];`
But its seem the compiler cannot decide which one of the function to use.

the propeties of the classes is:

```
class XOBoard {  // its only a part of the code.
 private:
  int n;
  Cell** Board;
};
class Cell {
 private:
  char ch;

 public:
  Cell(char ch = '.');
  char getCellValue() const;
  void setCellValue(char nch);
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Cell& Cell) {
    output << Cell.ch;
    return output;
  }
};
```

Comment: You cannot distinguish functions by their return type.

Comment: so how can i use do it?

Comment: Why not `char c = board1[{1, 2}].getCellValue();`?

Comment: You could also overload `operator char()` on the `Cell` class.

Comment: As an aside, your if conditions are incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisMM, thank you, i've set the overload function in the Cell.h and its work.
my bad!

Comment: does this answer your question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type

Comment: Assuming they are both members of the same class, they will cause ambiguity.   The compiler can only distinguish between overloaded functions based on the arguments and (for a non-static member function) the type of `this`.    Return type cannot be the only difference in specification of the same function - which is what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload only by return type, you might add const qualified in your case:

```
Cell& operator[](std::pair<int, int> pos);
char operator[](std::pair<int, int> pos) const;
```

so

```
void Print(const XOBoard& board)
{
     std::cout << board[{1, 2}]; // Fine, call const overload.
}

void Play(XOBoard& board)
{
     board[{1, 2}] = 'O'; // Fine, call non-const overload.
}
```

But

```
XOBoard board1;
//...
char c = board1[{1, 2}]; // Call non-const version as board1 is not const.
```

So, you have to provide `operator char` and possibly other operator to `Cell` to be usable in both context.

From what you shown, I would add a non-const getter to `Cell`

```
char getCellValue() const;
char& getCellValue();
void setCellValue(char nch);
```

and then

```
char& operator[](std::pair<int, int> pos);
char operator[](std::pair<int, int> pos) const;
```