# Could C++ template function overload on return parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, types, return, overloading

With same template declaration, is it possible to differ two functions with same name, same param list, but different return type?

```
template <class T>
int f()...

template <class T>
short f()...
```

Or, need some special code to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a situation that cannot be resolved by casting the result?

Comment: If everything is the same besides the return type, how would you know which function to call?

Comment: It’s possible using the [overloaded return type pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9569120/1968).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed have function templates with same name, same parameter types, and same return type (but you cannot for regular functions).

```
template <class T>
int f() {/*..*/}

template <class T>
short f() {/*..*/}
```

But then their usage is not really easy/fine:

```
auto i = static_cast<int(*)()>(&f<float>)(); // Call int f<float>
auto s = static_cast<short(*)()>(&f<float>)(); // Call short f<float>
```