# how to overload unique_ptr in a class . i am getting compilation error

Tags: c++, memory, c++14, unique-ptr

```
std::unique_ptr<Manager>& checkManager(std::unique_ptr<Manager> &p1) 
 {
   if(p1 && p1->getName().find("Manager") != std::string::npos ){
      std::cout<<"Manager exists"<<endl;
   }
   return p1;
 }

//overloading by unique ptr
 std::unique_ptr<Manager> checkManager(std::unique_ptr<Manager> p1) //by value passing uniq ptr
 {
   if(p1 && p1->getName().find("Manager")!=std::string::npos) {
      std::cout<<"Manager exists"<<endl;
   }
   return std::move(p1);
 }
```

i have overloaded these methods . in main when i am calling both i am getting error that function argument does not match . how to call these two methods separately from main.

Below is how i am calling  these methods

```
 auto& resultRef = checkManager(mp1);  // it gives compilation error
 auto result = checkManager(std::move(mp1)); // it works
```

Below is the error:
**more than one instance of overloaded function "checkManager" matches the argument list:**

Comment: Please always post the complete code and the complete error message with you question.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Both functions will always return `p1`, no matter if the name is found or not. Is this on purpose ?

Comment: you cannot overload based on return type alone (not related to unique_ptr). Also Do do you really want `checkManager` to transfer ownership of the pointer to the caller? If so `getManager` would be a better name.

Comment: i have added error i am getting in gcc compiler

Comment: [Overloading by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type)

Comment: Regardless of the return type, you cannot overload a function taking a parameter by value with a function taking a parameter of the same type by reference. This, again, is not related to `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the first overload to be called for lvalues and the second for rvalues.

You can do just that by making the second overload take an rvalue reference:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Manager>& checkManager(std::unique_ptr<Manager> &p1) {
    // ...
    return p1;
}

std::unique_ptr<Manager> checkManager(std::unique_ptr<Manager> &&p1) {
    // ...
    return std::move(p1);
}
```

Before, when called with an lvalue, even though `unique_ptr` isn't copyable, it is still just a good a match (`T&` doesn't beat `T` when passed a `T` lvalue).

Now, the second overload cannot be called with an lvalue, so it is no longer ambiguous.

Comment: thanks for the detailed code . it solved compilation issue